# What is the disincentive for failure to RTFM / embrace GIYF?

Tags: discussion

Building on [Embrace the Non-Googlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers) and [How should you respond to “Give me a fish” / RTFM questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2686/how-should-you-respond-to-give-me-a-fish-rtfm-questions) I'm curious as to what acts as a disincentive for those who choose to ignore the manual and can't be bothered to Google.

Downvoting a question comes at a cost to those who do the downvoting (whereas finding another way to ask the same question - but hopefully avoid downvotes - is free) ... perhaps there could be a threshold to allow question downvoting without penalty if a user has asked X questions with a zero upvoted:downvoted ratio over the life of his or her account?

It seems like there should be a disincentive which avoids creating an unanswered questions graveyard/moderation tarpit *and* gives those doing the asking a reason to consider cracking a book before firing off another question.

Comment: Why do you assume an RTFM question is typically unanswered?  They very rarely are and draw lots of votes.

Comment: @Hans_Passant - Perhaps that should be "read the (introduction of) the manual" - random examples from unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878482/make-dynamic-call-with-jquery-treevew http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787385/sub-query-in-protege-4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880303/setting-up-cruisecontrol-under-tomcat6