# It takes two to tango?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

Suggested edits approval or rejection always needed only one reviewer here on Meta.

Today I noticed it requires two. ([Example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9098))

Is this change intentional, or some glitch? If on purpose, what is the reason for the change?

Worth to mention that on Stack Overflow it now takes three instead of two. ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/816767))

Comment: I don't object to it requiring two - but an announcement would have been nice.

Comment: @Chris I second that, searched high and dry before posting this.

Comment: Also I see today, [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/816393) [requires](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/816392) [more](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/815992) [than](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/815989) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/815988) [approval](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/815977)

Comment: @hims056: Oooo, maybe they finally implemented that a reject vote cancels out an approve vote (and vice versa)? I like this, but where's the announcement??

Comment: @animuson Yes. At least it will reduce [this message](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pCb3h.png)

Comment: Just realized my answer was about SO and you were asking about MSO... so I am changing it to a comment... On SO, it looks like there was a change to require 3 approvals and not actually have rejects cancel out.  Check out this [suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/816718) for an example.  There were 2 approvals, 2 rejects, then 1 more approval.  Maybe the number of votes required to approve an edit was increased by one StackExchange wide?

Comment: @animuson nope, that's not the case. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/816767) with three "pure" approve votes required to approve.

Comment: @psubsee2003 thanks, didn't notice that it affected the main site either. :)

Comment: Oh thank goodness it takes more than 2 votes to approve or reject something... if this is permanent, I'm doing my happy dance.

Comment: @Little this might help reduce the "false positives" coming through in the main site, but not sure it's a good idea to do that network wide.. sites with less traffic should be fine with one or two reviewers. :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In response to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted), we've bumped up the number of reviews required to approve or reject a suggested edit:

- **Network-wide:** two reviews per edit suggestion.
- <s>**Stack Overflow:** three reviews per edit suggestion.</s>

Moderators and the original poster can review suggested edits instantly in cases where an insufficient number of users are available to review them.

---

**Update:** The number of reviews per edit suggestion required on Stack Overflow has been dropped from 3 to network-wide 2.

Comment: +1 for implementing this, -1 for not telling us before you implement it, +1 because Greece just scored against Slovakia.

Comment: Hey man, I just got back from a week's vacation - I'm a bit slow! (And I don't mean "sluggish")

Comment: I suspect this will have little impact. You've still got badges creating a Cobra Effect. All you've done is increase the number of opportunities for people to cash in on.

Comment: @Shog9 a whole week? That Denver office opening party must have been some shindig!

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter First thing I thought, reading your comment: "What's a Cobra Effect?" Second thing: "I'll [check Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobra_effect)." Third thing: "I'm upvoting that." (Fourth thing: "How can I link to the Wikipedia entry for that term without being boring?")

Comment: Thanks, I also got worried about bad edits slipping through more than before with the new system and think this will help, at least until step B is in place. :)

Comment: @PopularDemand The Cobra Effect was also on reddit earlier today, so suddenly everyone is experiencing the Baader-Meinhof Effect now :)

Comment: @yoda I don't use reddit, so I didn't see that initial reference to the cobra effect, but at least I got to look up [Baader-Meinhof Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cognitive_biases#Frequency_illusion). Those who are more familiar with recent German history than I am will be unsurprised to learn that my initial search for Baader-Meinhof took me to a page that had nothing to do with the Baader-Meinhof effect; it directed me to Red Army Faction, AKA the Baader-Meinhof Gang. Baader-Meinhof. Baader-Meinhof. Baader-Meinhof.

Comment: Maybe we could go back to one with a certain number of reputation? 30k?

Comment: @Shog9 Abuse of `/review` for badges shouldn't make a mess of the privilege structure - a user who is able to unilaterally edit should be able to unilaterally approve or reject a suggested edit.  Wouldn't a better approach be more appropriate to prevent coasting through `/review`?

Comment: And what happens when there are an insufficient number of moderators?

Comment: @Shane: anyone with edit rights can still approve an edit without assistance - as long as they're willing to edit.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm not sure what you mean by "as long as they're willing to edit"?  See also: http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3781

Comment: @Shane: see [my response there](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3781/users-with-editing-privileges-can-no-longer-approve-edits/3826#3826).

Answer (score 13):

This may be good for SO, but it's a bogus hoop to jump through on some 2.0 sites.

I suggest that reviews from 20k+ users (and probably 10k+ users also) count as 2 reviews on SE 2.0 sites that are lower traffic. When either of us could make an edit by oursleves with no approval, it seems ridiculous that it takes both me (20k) and another user (10k) to [approve an edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/8666). The only reason I didn't make the edit myself is somebody had already gone to the work.

Comment: Psst, if you hit "improve", make a further improvement, then mark the suggestion is helpful, *everybody* wins!  A workaround, I admit...

Comment: There are quite a few high-rep robo-reviewers, so I fully support the increase in approvals needed as an experiment on *Stack Overflow*. However, it's had seemingly little to no effect so far anyway. (Unclear as I am, it means I basically agree. ;)

Comment: @Charles: Oh that makes sense. Because every hoop needs a loop-hole.

Comment: @J.Steen: It sounds like we need a way to review reviewers, not suggestions.

Comment: Who reviews the reviewers? ;)

Comment: I agree that it's a good idea but only on low traffic sites. [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) is hardly low traffic site.

Comment: Same problem on Photo-SE: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2565/new-review-system-reduces-our-ability-to-help-out-new-users