# Is it possible to flag edit reviews as invalid?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

This edit was approved:  https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4179699.  However, bolding a few occurences of "github" and "SELinux", and changing "I have to" to "I've to"  seems like a very poor edit indeed.  The editor has had 131 edit suggestions approved, and 56 edit suggestions rejected, and it seems to me a good number of those approved should probably have been rejected  ( [this one, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22072784/revisions) )

I could roll this edit back, but I don't know if the edit review link will still work at this point, and I'm not yet sure of the guidelines around that.

My question is this:  Is it possible to flag individual *reviews* for attention so that our bored and underworked moderators can send the reviewers a helpful message about editing, and possibly give them a temporary break from suggested edit reviews?

Of course, I'm new to hitting the suggested edit reviews (I generally stay in the close vote list) - I may be wrong about the validity of the edit.  If that's the case please let me know in no uncertain terms.

Comment: I agree, this edit is a nonsense.

Comment: "I've to"...  I don't think I have ever seen or heard someone use that phrase, **ever**.  They must have been short 2 characters for the minimum acceptable edit.  The person suggesting the edit should also get a temporary break.

Comment: The same guy has made a lot of changes like that today. I managed to reject a handful of them but most of them got approved quickly :-(

Comment: This edit review would not have been approved, if we had a [tennis rule](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219916) in place.

Comment: 100% agree.  Sorry I didn't find the duplicate, but it also led me to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits , which is possibly a better choice to send people to from this question.