# Close an opinion based question with a bounty on it

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, bounties, specific-question, vote-to-close

I just found this question on the CSS featured page:
[Is a table layout appropriate for full-screen single-page HTML applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964825/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-of-full-screen-single-page-applications-in-html)

This looks like a pretty obvious "primarily opinion based" question, if I'm not mistaken.

It even references itself as a variation of a closed question:

> This question is a variation of this popular one: [Why not use tables
>   for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)

I tried to vote to close, but of course you can't do that on bountied questions, so I'm looking for a little assistance.

Comment: Wow, that was fast...

Comment: even after it has edited, would this question be closed as opinion-based?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've voted to close it as `primarily opinion based`.  I intervened because I feel like it should be closed, and it has a bounty on it (which keeps it from being closed through normal community moderation).

If the OP can make the following changes to the question:

- take out the 'can I haz internet blessing plz' phrase
- articulate an actual problem they're trying to solve
- explain why they need this problem answered (I mean, really. Is it because CSS is hard?)
- rephrase the question so it doesn't appear like they're asking someone's opinion.

Overall, it's a great topic of discussion, just not a great question for Stack Overflow.

Normally, if a post doesn't have a bounty, vote to close it.  If it does have a bounty, that's an exceptional case where you can flag for moderator attention (Flag -> 'Other' -> Reason for flagging (more than a few words, please).

Comment: Do you know if there are any particular reasons why we can't vote to close on questions with bounties, other than handling a possible bounty refund?

Comment: @apaul34208, related: [Allow users to vote to close bountied questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121448/allow-users-to-vote-to-close-bountied-questions)

Comment: I agree, the ending was bad. But the problem they're trying to solve seemed clear from the beginning: implementing the layout using DIVs and a host of other tricks is "pure hell", and they're considering tables as a cleaner, more maintainable solution. They need it answered because they don't know the answer. If "CSS isn't hard" was a reason to close a question, you could close just about everything with the [tag:css] tag. Go ahead, I'll wait. At some level, every question has a tinge of subjectivity; that's OK. I've edited and voted to re-open this one. I see little wrong with it.

Comment: @CodyGray "Which is more maintainable" is normally a question that solicits opinions. I can see ways where it wouldn't be, but that would require a very well defined problem with very well defined success criteria.

Answer (score 3):

Flag it for the moderators. I've successfully used an **other** flag with text similar to "Off topic opinion based question protected from closure by a bounty" to have those questions closed.

Comment: @animuson: Thanks for the edit. Habit. :-)