# Bounty shielding question from closure?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, bounties

This is a subset of my question earlier about how some questions survive while others exist, despite seeking legal advice that is clearly personal to them. I've decided if that is the law of the land, and people want to cast votes to close, I'm on board. Today, I ran across a couple questions of this type. One new user wrote a question, and with posting it, also posted a bounty. The Q is a clear plea for legal advice. The person, having come from another SE community had enough reputation to post a bounty, unlike other new uses, which prevents it from being closed.

My question is, why does the existence of a bounty shield a question from closure?

Comment: Please see the answers on this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121448/allow-users-to-vote-to-close-bountied-questions

Comment: Just to be clear, the user did not post the bounty with the question, but waited a few days. You can't add a bounty right away. Also, was it [this question](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/3641/us-trademark-for-irish-limited-company-application-by-owner)?

Comment: I apologize, I thought I was on law meta when I asked this, as it was related to a question I had asked about this issue, last week and I wanted to link it to that one. I've read link question, thanks, and I am aware you can flag, but that is different than a community vote, and if the rules say these questions need to be  edited or closed, because specific legal advice can lead to potential issues, I just wanted to pose to the community the question of, how can one be shielded from community vote to close, when I am simultaneously reviewing others with votes to close based on same issue?

Comment: Wrong dupe. Found proper one, will use hammer to fix this.

Comment: Do all SE communities have the same rules for closure? I think you posted that one yesterday, or someone posted it or another close to it, and I was just reading it when my laptop died. When I signed back on with power, it was gone! (I have history set to clear at shutdown). Again, I didn't meant to post this here, but in Law meta, which is were I had searched for answers. I thought all the communities had there own rules relating to why you'd close. I'm sure you can see why the analysis is a bit different in the law, due to the ramifications of detrimental reliance.

Comment: I never even knew this was the case (bounty preventing close votes) until yesterday. It does strike me as bizarre, reading all the comments against the practice (that span a course of years) that SE didn't change it so that if a bountied question gets closed, that's the one case in which it gets returned. DV, flagging or Mod intervention are not the same, as this is community decision when close votes are pending. Anyhow, no big deal and thanks.

Comment: Missed your comments (assuming they were directed at me?) due to no @-ping. Anyway, yes the closure rules and bounties are the same on all sites of Stack Exchange. While it might look weird that question with active bounty can't be closed by ordinary users, that's how things work and looks like everyone are happy with it. :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, it was just directed at whomever cared ;)  I ended up reading all the questions that dealt with the issue. It appears there was quite a bit of dissension where many users thought that particular feature should be amended, but it seems that it never got any traction. I didn't realize the rules applied across sites - I thought each site may have their own rules for closure as each deals with site/topic specific issues. I'm aware now, though, that it is what it is. The question ended up getting closed anyway, and the bounty refunded, as decided by mod (and prob flags?!?)

Comment: @gracey209 yeah, moderators usually react to flags. And as for cross sites, everything is the same except required reputation for specific privileges, which is different between beta sites and non-beta sites. The sites are different in design, and of course contents. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I get that now. I really meant to post on law meta, but it ended up that there were a bunch of relevant references I got from here....so useful mistake. Now, all I really need to know is how you get your dragon's eyes to blink! Love

Comment: lol, took lot of searching but finally found it. Cheers, and good luck with future questions! :)