# Bounties and Low Quality Posts Queue

Tags: discussion, bounties, low-quality-posts

While reviewing a question in the low quality posts queue I ran into an issue with the question having a bounty which prevented me from taking action on the post. I had intended to vote to close the question because in my mind it did not look okay and it could not be salvaged through an edit. When I went to cast my close vote I got the error saying questions with a bounty can't be closed.

Should questions with bounties be excluded from queues that users are not able to take all actions on? In this case since only a moderator would be able to cast a close vote after handling the open bounty shouldn't this question have only been available for them to review?

I am not suggesting that an item in the review queue should get around restrictions things like close or delete votes rather that it should be limited to moderators or employees who can still take action on them.

Answer (score 2):

It does seem like bad UI design to present the user with a close option only for the system to reject it if you try to use it. Why give you a choice you can't take?

A better UI would be to offer to custom flag such posts directly from the queue when the question has a bounty so you can choose that rather than the closure action you can't take. Choosing that would notify a moderator to take the action you can't take yourself. Given that so few posts have bounties on I can understand why that edge case wasn't really dealt with very well though.

To be clear, I'm suggesting bountied questions would have Moderator flag, Edit and Looks OK options rather than the current Closure, Edit, Looks OK options.

If you think a post needs to be closed but it has a bounty on it you can always flag it for moderator attention and ask a moderator to do it for you. You'd need to explain clearly why it should be closed and you'd have to navigate to the question outside the queue in order to flag it.

There are so few moderators and employees compared to everyone else that if we left posts to them, they probably wouldn't get reviewed at all and the function of bounties isn't to prevent off-topic posts being closed, it's to allow unloved but on-topic questions to get answers.

Comment: Or maybe just make bountied questions eligible for closure like any other.

Comment: @user3840170 [that idea has already been suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121448/allow-users-to-vote-to-close-bountied-questions)

Comment: Upon thinking about it more I don't agree with this answer. If the error really is just presenting a radio button that can't be used that would leave the user with two options. Marking it as okay or marking it as editing the question. In the case I mention neither of those are actually correct options to take leaving me with the choice of skipping the review or making a bad choice.

Comment: @JoeW I'm explicitly suggesting not presenting a radio button with an option that can't be used by replacing it with an option that can be used that would ask a moderator to do for you what you can't do yourself. Then I give you a workaround that you can use with the current UI.

Comment: I understand, I just don't see the point. Why spend a users time reviewing a question that the only action they can take on is to flag it for a moderator to review? The question has already been flagged by users for review so should it really be flagged by more users to say it needs reviewed? As you say this is a fairly rare occurrence so it wouldn't add much to the moderator workload and having a user flag it ends in the same result.

Comment: I feel like you're both suggesting the same thing but with different words.

Comment: TLDR, the main concern is there's no action you can take. JoeW suggests just not showing bountied questions in review, robert suggested giving you an action you can take. Both solve the problem, robert's suggestion has the added benefits of the post still getting reviewed, and these posts being pre-screened by the community to avoid wasting moderator time. In both cases, the queue stops wasting reviewer time.

Comment: @KevinB I don't consider adding another flag for a moderator to review as taking a useful action. As that action requires the close vote privilege it doesn't make sense to have a review I can't vote to close.

Comment: @JoeW your solution effectively does the same, but doesn't let the community indicate when a mod flag isn't necessary... it just sends all bountied questions that end up here to mods, or none of them.

Comment: @KevinB My solution moves it to a moderator queue for review as a user has already flagged the question and I don't see the point of asking more users to add a flag to it.

Comment: @JoeW if it can be fixed by editing then it doesn't need to go to a moderator, it's only closure that needs a moderator so your position is that it's been incorrectly flagged and it therefore needs to be correctly flagged. My solution allows you to pick mod flag/edit/OK as options rather than close/edit/looks OK.

Comment: And if it can't be fixed by editing it is wasting the users time by having the flag it for moderator attention. Honestly with how infrequently this happens (as you state) I don't see why it can't just be sent straight to the moderators to deal with as it won't increase their work that much.

Comment: On Stack Overflow for instance there are 27 moderators vs 144,581 people with the reputation to review low quality posts. If edits can fix posts then those edits should be handled by non-moderators if possible.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't change the fact that this kind of situation is a pretty rare occurrence and that there is no reason to waste a users time to flag something with a moderator flag instead of just having a moderator take care of it in the first place. Also we shouldn't be rejecting this just because of the situation on a single site.

Comment: @JoeW by that definition, any review that ends in "looks ok" is wasted reviewer time?

Comment: it would be a fair claim to make, imo, that having to review something that doesn't need to be reviewed is in fact a waste of time, but that defeats the purpose of the system. It just sucks that the system has a flaw related to bounties. Given all the problems bounties cause, and attention it saps toward useless questions, i'd argue the best solution is removing bounties... but that'll never happen.

Comment: @KevinB I would disagree, as when enough users finish mark it as "looks okay" the review is finished and no further action is required. However in this case you can have every user that sees it mark is as flag for moderator action and while the review may get marked as complete there is still further action required by a moderator to review and take action as needed. The issue here is if the question needs to be closed there is nothing that a user can do to work towards that goal besides just putting another flag on it for someone else to look at.

Comment: @JoeW and, to be fair, it's also fairly unlikely for a mod flag to actually result in closure either. Normally, it is decided to let the bounty play out to avoid refunding the cost, particularly when the bounty has been live for more than a day or two.

Comment: However, there's still value in the review existing, as it's sitll possible for the review outcome to be an edit. If there's nothing to do, then, there's nothing to do, but we can't just throw out all bounty reviews because sometimes there's nothing to do.

Comment: @KevinB And that would be a final result as well since they have the ability to remove the bounty and close the question if they feel that is the correct answer while other users just have the option to flag it for a moderator for review. That action doesn't do anything to put an end on the question rather it just passes the decision to someone else to figure out what to do.