# Prevent upvotes for duplicates, or carry upvotes to master question

Tags: voting, duplicate-questions, feature-request

Questions that are duplicates and triplicates are still asked, even though the automatic "Related Questions" list that appears **must** be showing them!

These re-asked questions still get upvotes even after a question has been closed as a duplicate. To further discourage the questions, perhaps prevent upvotes to them after they've been closed? Or transfer the upvotes to the master (canonical or original)?

Also, this might help meta question [Please charge rep for questions after threshold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/please-charge-rep-for-questions-after-threshold).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We are unlikely to do this, because voting is an important axis of expressing disagreement with a closure.

Comment: I thought that voting to reopen was important for expressing disagreement with a closure. I only upvote the questions that are helpful in some way to me (eg, a question that I've had at one point in time) or just plain interesting.

Comment: But how to prevent the case when someone deliberately asks duplicate questions to get some upvotes to increase their reputation? They have nothing to lose here, even if their questions get closed after a while.

Answer (score 3):

Like Atwood said, voting is the primary method that people without much moderator power on the site can point out whether they agree or disagree with a particular action taken by higher ranked editors. Often times you'll see a question closed for a reason (even duplicate) and you'll have a lot of people upvote the question as an expression that they don't believe it is really a duplicate and that they want the question reopened.

Whether this makes them correct or not is irrelevant. I agree with Atwood on this on the idea of it being an unlikely feature.

Comment: Then they are doing it wrong. You vote on a question, not on what some moderator or the community has done to the question. Is this indicative of a larger issue?

Answer (score 1):

I disagree.  Sometimes a well-asked question is closed as a duplicate of a poorly-asked one -- but the poorly-asked one already has answers, so reversing the direction of the duplicate would make things worse.  And transferring a vote on the well-asked duplicate to the poorly-asked original would certainly be the wrong thing to do; a vote should reflect one's judgement of *the question being voted on*, not some other question that happens to be hanging around.

There are also different ways to ask the same question -- neither is *better* than the other, but they're *different* enough that the existing one didn't come up in a search.  Those duplicates are valuable and I sometimes upvote them even knowing that they're duplicates -- *especially* if my own search took me to the duplicate rather than straight to the original.