# Grant the original question the upvotes if another is closed as a duplicate of it

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

I have occasionally seen questions which have lot of duplicates, yet aren't as highly voted as one might expect given the views.

So I suggest that all upvotes (or some percent of it) on the duplicate be also applied to the original (up to some maximum, with consideration of duplicate's age, perhaps).

These questions have, after all, helped many users, and this might be one way to grant some proportionate reward from people who can't reward it (new users lacking the upvote privilege). I'd just like it if some measure of the approval that the dupe generated be applied to the original.

As an example, consider [this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list), which has as of this writing, 29 upvotes. It has well over 150 posts linked to it, some of which are upvoted. Guessing that 80% of these are actually duplicates of it, and 10% of these have an upvote, and say 60% (rounded up to next int) of the upvotes are given to it, it would get some 8 upvotes more. Not much, but still a definite boost to that question.

I'm not trying to punish duplicates (as intended in [Prevent upvotes for duplicates, or carry upvotes to master question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2700/prevent-upvotes-for-duplicates-or-carry-upvotes-to-master-question)), or completely transfer all votes from duplicate to original. I'd just like it if some measure of the approval that the dupe generated be applied to the original.

Comment: And what if you've already upvoted both?

Comment: @random A whole new type of vote fraud! In all seriousness though, this is an interesting proposal. I'd like to see what people think of it.

Comment: @random the only times I upvote both are when I found dupe first and original later, or when dupe is of significantly better quality than original (re: wording, data, etc.). But yes, I suppose, if there's tracking of who upvoted what, duplicate upvotes should be filtered out.

Comment: I've upvoted because it's a fascinating idea, though I'm not sure it will work in practice.

Comment: @random No, I don't really care if the dupe gets upvoted - I'd just like it if some measure of the approval that the dupe generated be applied to the original.

Comment: No thanks. Being the question that other questions are pointing to is a benefit in itself. Which will likely award it many more upvotes. If it doesn't, maybe the other one was better..

Comment: @Roombatron5000 we all know quality isn't the only factor in voting here.

Comment: Sometimes people seem to downvote the newer question as it shows lack of research given the original question exists. Those downvotes would then transfer to the original question which seems unfair.

Comment: @RobertLongson who said anything about downvotes? Upvotes only.

Comment: OK so I have an upvoted base question. I deliberately create duplicates, if the duplicates are downvoted then so what, if they are upvoted, profit.

Comment: @RobertLongson Exceptions such as (people who have voted for both) (people posting self-dupes)  (people voting for dupes to their posts) are reasonably obvious ones.

Comment: Gets complicated though, doesn't it?

Comment: @RobertLongson of course. A simple transference of all votes is neither useful nor desirable. Again, let me say: I'd just like it if some measure of the approval that the dupe generated be applied to the original, that's all. The calculation of that measure would be a bit complicated, to avoid fraud, and excessive reward. Think of it the way a review comment gets upvoted when another reviewer picks the same one - except this would actually benefit someone.

Answer (score 4):

This question is going to require a somewhat theoretical/philosophical answer. So, let's dig in. **What does reputation really represent, anyway?**

There are a couple of conflicting ideas on this point, and both need to be addressed. The first (and the one I'm partial to) is that it's a measure of trust the community has in a user to act in the best interests of the site. The other is that it's a measure of how many people you've helped - i.e. how 'reputable' your posts are.

---

**As a measure of trust, dumping large amounts of reputation onto someone is... somewhat defective.**

Reputation is a rough approximation of the trust we hold in someone to act in the best interest of the site. That's why we really don't want to be giving users large amounts of privileges at a time, and it's why the reputation graph is scaled the way it is. The more destructive a privilege, the more time you have to spend watching other people use it in order to gain access to it.

For example, 10k users gain the ability to delete questions. While this action can be reversed, in order to be undone it first has to be spotted, and so it's relatively high up on the 'destructiveness' meter. Only moderators have access to any tools which truly *destroy* information, and those are highly specific and very limited in capability. (Excluding staff for obvious reasons.)

Giving a user any significant amount of reputation either shortens the amount of time they spend watching and learning how to use Stack Exchange's tools, or just gives it to them without telling them how to use it. That's a problem, particularly when a question generates a *ton* of reputation for a user.

---

**As a measure of how many people you've helped, this proposal is... not entirely accurate.**

Much of the time, when a question is closed as a duplicate, it's either *better* or *equally good* at conveying information as the duplicate. When I search Stack Overflow, and find a duplicate that answers the question, rarely do I actually need to follow the link through.

And even supposing it did help, if I upvote the duplicate post, it's because *that post helped me*, not its duplicate target. I may not even have seen the duplicate. Perhaps the duplicate was poorly-formed, and I actually would have downvoted it. Or, alternately, and worse, perhaps the duplicate is in error, and my upvoting it would give reputation to a completely irrelevant question.

In other words, when votes are transferred without user review, there's a *lot* of room for potential error, and it may no longer represent the number of people you have helped.

---

**"Every user always has exactly one vote."**

There's an unspoken philosophy - and it goes unspoken not because we don't challenge it, but simply because it's rarely challenged at all. "Every user always has exactly one vote."

There's a balance here that should be obvious, but frankly, I wouldn't *want* my vote to count twice for different people anyway. I want to see the content that I'm voting on and evaluate it, and if I haven't seen it, I don't want to vote on it. This is precisely what the system currently does.

Holding two votes doubles my voting power, and that's not something I want to have happen, particularly when I haven't necessarily reviewed both things I'm voting on.

Comment: Overall, these are very good points. Just one thing: if the question were to be reopened, I'd expect the votes to be rolled back, so a duplicate in error shouldn't be that big a problem.

Comment: @muru There is an implicit assumption that the system is error-free in a number of ways - and I'd love to say it is, but it most definitely isn't. Much of the time, except on small sites, false duplicates are never undone.