# Will my question rank forward if I re-edit it?

Tags: support, questions

The questions are populated too fast.

Comment: @Baard: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1327572/list

Comment: It's also amazing that after 268 questions (and zero answers) this seems to be a complaint. A very vague complaint though. (Actually I added that tag.)

Comment: The most vague is that the author has 1793 reputation and still didn't read the FAQ.

Comment: **268** questions and **0** answers? Wow!

Comment: @Manni, those are the users who scare some people here. Not only 268 questions, but also almost 2000 reputation, implying editing rights while only 2 upvotes have been casted by this user... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/please-charge-rep-for-questions-after-threshold

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an edit will put your question to the top of the "hot" list if it isn't at -5 at that point.

However, only edit your question if you have some clarification or improvement to make. There's no sense in editing just to bump it.

If you edit the question six times, it will automagically become a community wiki and you will be unable to earn rep from it.