# Change flag tooltip for comment flags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, flags

Given that the flag mechanism has been expanded and improved for both questions and answers and taking into consideration these [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15143/whats-with-all-the-rude-comments-recently) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17612/being-helpful-vs-being-hostile-and-why-so-is-supposed-to-stand-out-from-the-rest) that ended up more or less with a 'you should flag more' answer.

I think comment flags should be revamped. I suggest changing the tooltip to remove the "hate speech" part of it:

"Flag this comment as noise, offensive or spam"

This because I think that having both offensive and hate speech as flag reasons bias people towards a stronger definition of offensive than they would otherwise have, as illustrated by the sample comments that follow.

Remember offensive is a superset of hate speech, so it's not really necessary (hate speech is by definition offensive.)

Some relevant quotes:

```
One concern I have is inundating you with nitpicky stuff. Send me a note if you 
feel that's happening. I think -- based on the feedback here -- that I feel a 
little more free to flag comments that are simply rude but not patently 
offensive. 
– tvanfosson Aug 18 at 15:39
```

```
I think I've avoided flagging because I assumed it was reserved for personal 
attacks and specific malicious language (racist/sexist views, calling someone 
stupid, or offensive language in excess). But now that I know that it's meant 
to curb exactly what my email was about, I'll be sure to use the flag option 
for those situations. 
– Anthony 14 hours ago
```

I certainly cannot *prove* that these ideas are due to the biasing hate speech part of the tooltip provokes, but it certainly does give that impression to me. And there is nothing to *lose* from removing it. It's not as if our community needed a reminder to flag hate speech when it happens.

Answer (score 1):

[**Noise** was recently added as a reason to flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15290/are-all-the-1-comments-really-necessary).

When you flag a comment, it doesn't bug a moderator, it just works on its own. Plus, when you read it with commas and the OR, it's like a menu, you decide what you want to be flagging the comment for:

```
noise | offensive | spam | hate speech
```

Is there a dilemma when you spot a pointless add-nothing comment like, "+1 Good answer", but because it's not offensive or spammy, you won't flag?

If you can't decide, order a burger and just don't flag.

Comment: I think I've nailed my main (possibly wrong) idea: Having both offensive and hate speech bias people towards a stronger definition of offensive, as illustrated by the sample comments I've gotten from this site.

Comment: And flagged comments surface to moderators, according to the blog.

Comment: @random: +1 for saying the same basic thing I did, and not getting DVed into the negatives.

Answer (score -3):

I think it should be left alone. A moderator is not going to be reviewing the comment because you flagged it, that is not how comment flags work.

When you flag a comment, you are voting it to be deleted. Currently, I see "noise, offensive, spam or hate speech". I think that sums it up very well. This should not be taken lightly and I believe most of the people who use StackOverflow are capable of grokking logic like 'or'.

Comment: The moderator part is not the relevant idea.

Comment: @Vinko: But it shows a fundamental flaw in your understanding of the topic at hand.

Comment: Still hate speech is way too strong, I've read many times: "Well, I wanted to flag this comment but it's not that offensive" (which I'd attribute to the hate speech part of the tooltip)

Comment: I see "noise, offensive, spam or hate speech". I think that sums it up very well. This should not be taken lightly.

Comment: If anything, offensive is a superset of hate speech. "noise, offensive or spam" would be just as good at the seriousness part, but without turning people off.

Comment: @Vinko: I have more faith that our community understands simple logic like 'or'.

Comment: @Rich B: Good for you

Comment: @Vinko: So you honestly believe that the developers on SO.com are not capable of understanding simple logic? I find that a bit insulting.

Comment: @Rich: No. I honestly believe that newbies might get confused by the tooltip.

Comment: @Vinko: At what harm? A comment that was borderline wouldn't get deleted as quickly or at all?

Comment: I would imagine that comments just wouldn't get deleted at all, given that both a relatively new SO user and an expert SO user both got the impression that flags are for far more serious things than for what they really are (see the questions where those comments appeared: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17612/being-helpful-vs-being-hostile-and-why-so-is-supposed-to-stand-out-from-the-rest
 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15143/whats-with-all-the-rude-comments-recently)

Comment: @Vinko: They *are* pretty serious. You are voting to delete another person's contributions. If you have reservations about whether a comment is seriously offensive enough to delete based on the tooltip, you should not be flagging it.

Comment: And by the way, it seems to me that the one who isn't understanding the topic at hand is you: "If a comment is flagged by enough users it will be auto-soft-deleted. There is no penalty for this.. yet. Flagged comments will be surfaced to moderators, so if you have a problem with a comment, flag it."  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/comments-now-with-flags-and-votes/

Comment: @Vinko: I understand it just fine. But it needs enough votes, that is not the same as being visible to a moderator when you flag it, nor does it mean a moderator definitely will review it. It just means the mods will be able to go back and investigate a pattern of abuse if it is reported. Hard deleted or soft deleted, you are deleting someone's content. That is a serious responsibility.

Comment: @Rich: But what if you have those reservations only because the way the tooltip is phrased?

Comment: @Vinko: That would be good. You should always be on the cautious side when deleting someone's contribution.

Comment: Just like with everything else, there is no guarantee a mod will review it. A) it needs more votes as you say, so if somebody is trigger happy he'll not cause mayhem and B) removing the 'hate speech' part does not take any seriousness out of it. It seems that you just want to discourage flagging, where I just want to do the opposite, given the last few questions about new rude users and the like. Maybe you have a vested interest here? :-)

Comment: @Vinko: I do not want to discourage flagging at all. In fact, I encourage it. But to not understand the tooltip would mean you don't understand a simple logic 'or'. Anybody with any intelligence approaching average should be able to perform this simple logic. Therefore anyone who gives pause at an 'or' I *would* discourage from flagging. These people probably shouldn't even have the ability to flag or vote on the site, and it is a shame the site trusts them enough to allow them to.

Comment: @Rich: You can perfectly understand ors and get biased by the words in the tooltip. You can imagine given the other parts of the tooltip a stronger definition of offensive, for example. See the example comments above. Anyways, this is now too long a comment discussion for anybody else to read.

Comment: @Vinko: 'noise' does not confuse me when or'ed with 'hate speech'. I also don't believe our community is incapable of reading a comment thread. Discussion is what was requested, and is what was delivered.

Comment: @Rich: Of course it does not confuse anybody, because 'noise' is not a superset of 'hate speech'. 'Offensive' is and can and DOES confuse people (see above.)