# Could SE promote "community projects" for smaller sites?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

In order to get new questions, **[Startups SE Beta is hosting a "Startups Startup" event](https://startups.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146/what-about-a-startups-se-startup/191#191), where teams are creating a startup with virtually no monetary investment.** Any needed resources are reused from old projects (i.e. old domain names, unused hosting, etc.). They're using this to generate content by requiring every major decision backed by a new question.

This is a ***great*** idea to get new questions and content! Imagine the possibilities. I suggested that they donate any money generated, just to encourage people to participate. I started thinking about this idea and how it could be applied to a lot of sites on the Stack Exchange network. Arduino SE? We could do a small open source project!

Of course, all of these projects should be focused on creating new content while bringing the community closer in a fun way (with donations to charities/open source code as a great byproduct that can be "watermarked" to point to the SE community for advertising). I've seen competitive competitions get a lot of attention by a community.

Would this be feasible to do on a much larger scale? How could we refine this idea to benefit the whole network? We'll have to see how this plays out, but I'm actually really excited by this idea.