# How to deal with spam user posting ad in their profile page

Tags: discussion, profile-page, moderator-tools, spam, users

At our Stack Exchange site we have some users created recently that have no activity, simply a name and profile which contains an add for some car insurance quotes. How can we deal with users like that? Are there tools to report them to moderators and for moderators to flag them somehow or remove them?

Examples:

- https://devops.stackexchange.com/users/5426/car-insurance-estimator-geico
- https://devops.stackexchange.com/users/5411/insurance-companies-for-old-ca
- https://devops.stackexchange.com/users/5407/car-insurance-rate-quotes-comp
- https://devops.stackexchange.com/users/5408/online-car-insurance-quotes-ad
- https://devops.stackexchange.com/users/5405/car-insurance-providers-in-ma

This question is not actually answered in the question: *[Spam Profiles are getting my goat. Could we have better tools for mods to deal with profile spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303746/spam-profiles-are-getting-my-goat-could-we-have-better-tools-for-mods-to-deal-w)*

As the answers deal with automated detection of those users or some other algorithmic approaches. I'm wondering about the lack of moderation tools to allow flagging user profiles directly for spam and for moderators to delete flagged accounts. While this might seem a time sink for some bigger sites, it still should be an option for those who want to keep their SE site clean.

Comment: I think this is a dupe of [Delete old, unloved, users better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146458/179419), which is itself related to the [meta-tag:status-completed] [Delete old, unloved, users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146450/179419).

Comment: I don't want to wait until they become old. I want the spammers out of our SE now.

Comment: The other post deals with profiles of spammers with all spam content deleted or SEO accounts with links. But there are no links here and no content.

Comment: The question is really not answered. In any of the answers to the 'my goat' post. In particular the answers deal with automated detection. I'm asking for flaging users themselves for spam and for moderator tools to hide/delete these users.

Comment: Point is: there are no option yet to deal with those accounts yet. At best you can flag your own post and then link to the accounts but I'm sure the mods or SE staff is already on it given the sheer number. the OP of that other question is a Mod on SU. If that question gets answered, then this one will be as well. The dupe is appropriate.

Comment: I see the point. If there is a good solution for addressing this on SU, that should work for us as well.

Comment: Feel free to close this as duplicate, I've got my questions answered.

Comment: Vaguely, we don't have the *tools* to handle these efficiently in any way. That said, I appreciate these questions since it puts it forth to the powers that be on the network that... this is a real issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there tools to report them to moderators

You can't flag a user for mod attention unless they've posted. If your site's mods are active in chat, you could ping them there about the issue. Or you could raise a mod flag on a totally unrelated post to alert them to the existence of these spammers - all flags go into the mod dashboard, regardless of how relevant they are to the post actually being flagged.

> and for moderators to flag them somehow or remove them?

Moderators can easily **destroy** low-rep users if they were created to post spam or nonsense and have no other positive contributions. This is the usual way we get rid of spammers' accounts.

The latest flood of spammers on Super User is far too big to deal with like this (nearly 10,000 users, and there are rate limits on user destruction, which also takes several clicks per user), but if other sites have a more manageable amount of car insurance spammers, then the mods may be willing to nuke them. (I've already nuked a few on my mod site in the last couple of days.)

Comment: On DevOps it seems to be a small number so far: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users#pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&inname=Insurance&filter=!)RwdAtHpbCC7t)A)JmDw8OpL&site=devops&run=true

Comment: Would it be worth it to allow users to mark profiles themselves as spammers?

Comment: @JiriKlouda No, that could easily be abused (I've already seen users raising totally invalid spam flags on questions they don't like) for very little gain (aside from rare outbreaks like this one on SU, there are usually very few spammers per day on a given SE site - easily few enough for mods to handle).

Comment: I guess we can always bring it to the mods attention in chat.

Comment: @JiriKlouda as I said in devops chat yes ;)