# Spam (tobacco related) multiple accounts

Tags: support, profile-page, spam

Looks like all of https://stackexchange.com/users/23136292/tobacco-king?tab=accounts accounts are spam.

E.g. multiple users found on ruSO: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11819/176217

Comment: My understanding is that these will be tolerated as long as they only exist as dormant profiles with no actual spamming activity on the Q&A sites themselves.

Comment: @tripleee see posts [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303806/339911)

Comment: Well... how on earth do people actually find these users and read the spam if the user isn't posting anything? Doing a user search is the only way I can think of.

Comment: @Lundin according to the linked post on ruSO these accounts were found by badges (that can be awarded only once) awarded to users with same names.

Comment: @Luuklag Support requests cannot be dupes. And if this profile is classified as spam but never posted anything, there is really no other way to report it than making a meta post.

Comment: @Lundin there is no real request here either, just mentioning something. So there really isn't a question.

Comment: Reports can be made by email, contact link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105218/is-spam-in-the-about-me-field-a-reason-to-worry#comment321224_105228  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303746/spam-profiles-are-getting-my-goat-could-we-have-better-tools-for-mods-to-deal-w#comment987511_303746 etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flag abusive users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1336/282094)

Comment: Moderator's warning: Smoking on Stack Exchange causes low quality posts, burnination, and cancer of the unicorn.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spam accounts - how to handle?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112975/spam-accounts-how-to-handle)