# Fix tooltip for the red tags on the Tags page

Tags: bug, tags, tooltips, wording, moderator-tags

According to the latest information from the [Red tag set by user without diamond](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321714/339911) question, not the only ♦ moderators can set the red tags on questions.

Hence the tooltip for the red tags on the [Tags page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags) should be fixed to prevent misunderstanding:

> [image: red-tag-tooltip]

Seems the text should mention SO employees too.

The [moderator-tags](/questions/tagged/moderator-tags) tag description should be also fixed.