# Will a user be deleted or removed from a site if they were not active or did not log in for a long time?

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

I want to know if there is any rule to remove or deactivate a user, if they didn't login in. If such a rule exists, then I also want to know the exact number of days/months/years after which such removal takes place.

Comment: See [As per the new data retention policy, when will inactive accounts now be deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310446/as-per-the-new-data-retention-policy-when-will-inactive-accounts-now-be-deleted): if you've ever contributed anything to the site, your account will not be removed. If you've *never* contributed any posts to the site, it will be deleted if you don't visit for two years.

Comment: @Sonic not only posts. Even single edit or vote on some post would prevent auto deletion of the account.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 as is listed in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @Luuklag sure, but the comment in its current form is misleading.