# Is it possible to lose access to one of the Stack network's sites' memberships, while membership to other networks site's is still valid?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, network-profile

First, sorry that I do not know what is the correct word to use instead of *membership*.

What I mean by that word, is I joined the site and I could easily access my profile on that site by switching from my account on other sites(in the Stack network).

In addition to my current Stack network's sites' membership, I think I also joined the Electrical Engineering site, some time ago and I do not want to create a new account in such case.

This can simply be **my own mistake** due to failure to remembering!

Also, in term of warnings and being banned from that account, I have checked my emails and there were none. I use the same email account for all of my account.

Comment: Did you create any posts on Electrical Engineering? Can you find a link to one of them?

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine No, I did not create any post there.

Comment: Do you remember the name that you might have used? A search of that site's membership with "AKL" yields nothing. As far as I know, accounts aren't deleted for not being visited, they just lay dormant.

Comment: @W.O. yes that is my problem, I use the same name on all of the Stack network's sites'

Comment: If you didn't make any contributions using the other account (and assuming you're not misremembering), you can just join the site using this account and forget about it. If a mod finds your other account at some point in the future, they can request a merge. So, you'll end up with one account anyway.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Thank you. I will do that. Should I expect an error while creating the account in case I had an old account?

Comment: It's unlikely because it doesn't look like you have a profile with this account.

Comment: There is this user on electrical engineering: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/9934/akl but that is all lowercase, and precedes your other accounts by about 7 years.

Comment: @Luuklag  and   41686d6564standsw.Palestine Thanks. I created the account and there were no problem.

Comment: @W.O. there was a very rare [inactive users removal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310516/241919), but it was done in 2018 and for users having 1-rep only.