# Is it OK that I am currently  just asking questions (and not answering any yet)?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it OK to only ask questions? What is the percentage of users always asking questions, and users always answering?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106485/is-it-ok-to-only-ask-questions-what-is-the-percentage-of-users-always-asking-qu)

As someone with no formal programming training and someone who is committed to diving in and learning rigorously,  is it OK that I'm currently JUST asking questions and not answering any (yet)?

Is this looked down upon?

Comment: Also -- as long as you're asking good questions, that's great. ("Good questions" meaning, roughly, questions other people can learn from).

Comment: It's cool, but you can also help the community by simply voting up good questions; by editing grammar/spelling for non-native speakers, etc. And one day you can answer too!

Answer (score 1):

That's fine. Keep an eye on questions and help when you can.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start somewhere.  If people don't ask questions, there's no questions to answer!

Answer (score 0):

That's very much OK, and also try to mark an answer if it helps and rate some of the answers that you feel as relatively closer by UP ^. Then it be both satisfactory to you as well the answerer.