# jquery questions with too many answers

Tags: discussion, answers, noise-reduction

I know Jquery is a [pretty big thing (45,879 questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) for web developers (myself included), but surely a question as simple as "[how to download jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939401/noob-jquery-question)" doesn't require 6 answers...(and they weren't all posted at the exact same time)

I'm just wondering whether there is a trend to answer these simple questions instead of help make a single answer (or two) better...just seems overkill...

Comment: The whore what turns the most tricks gets the plushest mink from daddy

Comment: "how to download jquery" does not belong on SO voted to migrate to SU

Comment: @Nifle, just "not belonging on SO" doesn't qualify something for a move to SU. This question doesn't really belong on _any_ SE site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers like that are usually due to the [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite-on-mso) behavior. This is also particularly noticeable for basic `regex` and `c#` questions.