# Why not suggest that users provide more precise links to code references?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I noticed that when people provide a link for online references, they sometime post very general links. I don't know how about other references, but apple has a side bar with links to each part of visible document. So it's better to find the exact part of the document and find a link to it in side bar, and copy it for the answer. For example:

[image: Screenshot of the iOS Developer Library]

Link to `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` method:

[Precise link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW19) 
[General link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

To change it we can:
Add something about it to [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) and how to ask.
In "how to Answer" there is a topic called "Provide context for links", somewhere around it. 
For example we can do something like this, not everybody look here but...
[image]

Comment: Yeah, it's just thing to consider to those who post.

Comment: No, some how suggest to user that about to post a link, to consider precise link.

Comment: Picture shows, how to copy precise link to exact that method. For example [general link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

Comment: I'll just say that people probably can't be arsed to do so. How do you want to change that?

Comment: I think I understand now. You're suggesting that verbiage be added somewhere on the site encouraging users to provide precise urls and explain how to derive them from a page. Right-Click + Copy-Url VS just copying the url from the browser because sites like Apple's iOS API hide the specific section. Or something like that..

Comment: Yes, I suggest to encourage people in some faq "better answer" to do so.

Comment: Sure, it would be great if people would do this. It would also be great if they removed the parenthetical portion of MSDN links. But they don't, and they won't. And there's nothing I can imagine that will get them to do it if they aren't already doing it. If you can update your question with a *concrete suggestion* on how to motivate people to do this, then we'll have something. Until then, voting to close as "not constructive"—this isn't a good place to post your wish list for humanity. We all wish people would be less lazy and more competent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be the case that the poster was in a hurry or didn't want to forfeit their position as the first answer (a-la [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22368/175248)).

I would post a comment asking the answerer to make their link more specific and direct if applicable.  Better still, you could suggest an edit to the post and add a more specific link.