# People not reading questions

Tags: discussion, answers

I feel that the percentage of people quickly writing some clueless "answer" without even reading the question has grown drastically.  Maybe they're driven by this motivation: "someone can upvote my answer; and if it has negative score, I always can delete it".

What's even worse, many people put "revenge downvotes" if someone criticizes their answer.  I'd say, if this tendency continues to grow, this will make SO nearly useless.

UPD summarizing it up: the question is about the rating system that allows people to write completely irrelevant "answers" and still have positive account rating.

How do you think this can be changed? What would you change in Stack Overflow to make this problem go away without hurting the site?

Comment: What exactly is your question? How does this differ from the [FGITW problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite-on-mso)?

Comment: @slugster, FGITW is about "quick and bad" answers getting highest scores. My question is about rating system encouraging people to write completely irrelevant answers.

Comment: @Bart, see update.

Comment: Yes. I think we should delete our accounts at once. Otherwise, we will continue to get useless answers within minutes of posting our question(s), and lots of serial downvoting that the vote reversal script will choose to ignore. Also, we should delete our own answers because they were useless to start with and all we wanted were the points. Who cares about helping others? A repository of knowledge for millions of programmers? big joke.

Comment: @AsheeshR, wow, nice joke. However, many people _do_ care about rating the most, rather than about "helping" and "knowledge repository".

Comment: @user160319 Most of the answers are contributed by regular users of the site. Most regular users get used to the rating system and over time move above it. That is, motivation changes. The reason being that we have something called [hedonic adaptation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedonic_treadmill). Once I start getting +3 on my answers regularly, I start craving +5. Once that happens, I crave a +7. This of course is not sustainable. Hence, the emphasis on the voting and scores reduces over time, uptill the point it becomes a very small part of the real motivation behind answering.

Comment: @AsheeshR, this obviously don't apply to _all_ users, or even the most. If account rating is not supposed to be important for users, why it even exists?

Comment: Its a feedback mechanism that indicates the quality and the helpfulness of the answerer or the contributions of an asker to the site. The scores act as an initial hook for new users, and overtime, it becomes just another number. Even the users who are most hooked by the game, tend to write better answers as they move up the curve because they start craving better feedback.

Comment: @AsheeshR, so, you agreed my statement above - many users _do_ care about rating.

Comment: Yes, I am not disagreeing entirely. The motivation of just getting lots of votes with quick poor answers is temporal. All I am saying is that the portion would be small if we look at the total number of answers and answerers.

Comment: I'm sorry, what?

Comment: @AsheeshR, it might be temporal for users, but it's still dominant by percentage of users.

Comment: I *think* there is an answer ban if you have too many downvoted deleted answers. (Equivalent to the question ban) That would largely address the problem you mention. I can't seem to find any details, though.

Comment: @Pekka 웃, or just keep negative score of deleted answers?

Comment: @user yeah, I think they do that already internally. That's what an "answer ban" would amount to if it really exists (I'll ask Tim)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use gamification to entice participation, you'll naturally have some side effects, such as FGITW and people writing answers after reading only the first sentence of a question. It's nothing really new. The difference between this and FGITW is the fastest guns keep revising, which isn't always the case for someone that didn't read the question at all.

Yet, these completely off the wall answers don't tend to live for more than a few minutes before being down voted into oblivion and in many cases removed, so there's no danger of them actually being presented to a visitor in a way that could be mistaken as cherished.

The scenario you describe is just a side effect of the game - just like really smelly sweat at a sporting event. It's a very annoying, but also *temporary* phenomenon. I don't see it as a major problem, but I do understand the annoyance. Fortunately, that's really all it is.

Comment: I can't agree that those answers always are downvoted and removed. This is an "I upvote you, you upvote me" game, which makes overall quality of answers decrease with time.

Comment: @user160319 Votes are anonymous. There is no quid pro quo. Moreover, whereever there is (through comments for example), there are scripts that check for them too.

Comment: Anonymity doesn't mean there can't be "quid pro quo".

Comment: Tim, do you know whether the answer ban works according to the same principles as the question ban (ie. lots of bad deleted answers lead to the ban)?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes - the same basic principles, deleted answers do count. However, answer bans are a little more difficult trigger; they allow for new users that don't quite understand what the answer box is for initially.

Comment: @user160319 Cross voting (what you describe) is detected and reversed by the system _most_ of the time. If you strongly suspect it's happening and isn't being reversed, you can flag and ask a moderator to check. When it comes to answers that _completely_ miss the question, you can down vote, edit, and occasionally flag. If the answer isn't even _close_ to what the question asked for, you can flag it for moderator attention and explain what's going on. Note, _wrong_ != _not even close_. Still, as long as folks see there's something wrong with it by the score - it's not actively harmful.

Comment: I deliberately didn't mention the answer block here, however Pekka did in his answer. It does trigger in these circumstances quite often - but _please do not use your votes strategically to ensure it triggers for a specific user_ .. and help them write better answers if you can.

Comment: @Tim Post, sounds not as a reliable solution. Why not keep ratings from deleted questions instead?

Answer (score 3):

This problem is already being addressed by the system, as confirmed by Tim Post in his [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184045/people-not-reading-questions/184047?noredirect=1#comment562245_184047) above. If you gain a significant number of downvotes on your answers, you will eventually be banned from answering - just as you are eventually banned from asking when asking a lot of badly-rated questions.

So - when you see bad-faith, lazy answers, just downvote them. It's the best thing you can do and it's effective.  The automatic ban will take care of users systematically posting bad answers in the hope to farm rep.

If you want to avoid confrontations, simply refrain from commenting. Voting without commenting is a perfectly legitimate thing to do.

Comment: Yeah, it will kick in eventually. It's also the easiest of the blocks to get out of - all you have to do is provide a working and moderately optimal solution, which is much easier than trying to clean up a bad question. Just don't see the block as the end for which your votes become the means - if someone can be helped with writing answers, then please do help them. The answer block is a generic catch - it also slows down spammers, trolls and others that somehow fail to catch a moderator's attention. It wasn't implemented  _specifically_ for this, but does serve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> Last time I feel that percentage of people quickly writing some
>   clueless "answer" without even reading question carefully grows
>   drastically. Probably they are driven by this motivation: "someone can
>   upvote my answer; and if it has negative score, I always can delete
>   it".

This is likely addressed in [What is FGITW and SCITE on MSO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18014/175248)  To distill it:  **fast answerers will get in first, then revise their question to be correct.**  Oh, and negative scores will have an adverse effect on the answerer in due time.

> What even worse, many people put "revenge downvotes" if someone criticizes their answer.

This is covered (in some part) by [What is serial downvoting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/175248)

If you do feel that you're the victim of "revenge downvoting", then give it a day or so, and if the system determines you were the victim of serial downvoting, then it will be overturned.

Then again, if you're downvoted, it's only -2 reputation per instance.  Not exactly the end of the world.  If there are *a lot* of downvotes on a question/answer of yours, then evaluate the quality of said question/answer instead of presuming others are out to get you.

> How do you think this can be changed? What would you change in Stack
>   Overflow to make this problem go away without hurting the site?

I can't say I see it as a problem, exactly.  It may be an annoyance, or a hindrance, but not really a problem.  FGITW has its legitimate place, and those that egregiously abuse it do get their comeuppance.

Comment: revenge downvoting is not necessarily serial.