# Accept my own answer over others already accepted answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I have asked on question on S.O site. This was a question for which I knew the answer. But by the time I posted my answer there was an other guy who posted an answer. Since this answer was to the point I accepted the answer in-spite of adding my own answer which was more detailed and researched.

Over the time this question has become a popular question(1000+ hits today) When I read it today I feel that my answer makes for a more detailed and researched answer.

Now I am in a dilemma whether I should change the stance and accept my answer or leave it as is and let the users decide which is a better answer.

Rejoinder : Current the number of votes are at 6(other person) v/s 5(my answer). At some point if the number of votes on my answer outperforms the other person, would that be the right time to accept my answer?

Edit : The question in discussion is [Difference between Minimum cache lifetime and Expiration of cached pages](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83315/difference-between-minimum-cache-lifetime-and-expiration-of-cached-pages?lq=1) 
I would be glad to know a general answer as well :)

Comment: Next time, tick the checkbox that says *Answer your own question* ;)

Comment: How come I was so blind. Looks like everyone knows about this option :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At some point if the number of votes on my answer outperforms the
>   other person, would that be the right time to accept my answer?

Accepting an answer totally depends on you.

You can accept any answer or your answer if you like. Since the question you linked has a much detailed answer from you, I feel that should be marked as accepted since it would provide a better reference for future visitors. You can upvote the other answer *(but that too is totally your choice)*.

You should know that you can post answer with your questions. See: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

In StacExchange, *accepted answer* means that answer helped me the most and solved my problem. People having a similar problem and see your question will look at the accepted answer first. You are the one to judge which answer is more helpful. Since the question belongs to you, you are the one who knows which is the best answer to that problem.

In your situation, I guess, you thought you will steal his rep but which is more important for you? Good quality answer or the answer which do not belong to you?

There are known issues like [What is FGITW and SCITE on MSO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22368/173052) . Your situation do not fit any of them.

Accepting the right answer is your choice. Maybe you can upvote other answer and then un-accept it so you can do your best to balance rep difference, if reputaion is the concern in your mind.

Next time do not forget to choose *Answer your own question* checkbox.