# Fishing for reputation on hot questions/answers?

Tags: discussion, reputation, hot-questions

Mostly, I only answer and comment on "hot questions".  I have legitimate reasons for doing so, but sometimes I worry I am "fishing" for easy reputation on popular questions while other hard-working SE users are busy picking up questions from the "questions" list.

Is it wrong (or irresponsible) to answer only "hot questions"?

**Background**

My SE philosophy is to remain silent unless I am certain I have something to contribute.  I find browsing the list of new questions to be a poor use of my time, since 99% of those are outside my expertise.  As a result, most of my answers end up being for old questions related to topics I am researching, or something that caught my eye on the "hot questions" list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think it matters how users find questions to answer.

I think the most important thing for Stack Exchange sites is that clear questions receive clear answers which are of as high quality as possible.

Answer (score 5):

Ask yourself a couple of questions on this one:

- Do you want to help people? Are your answers helping people?
- Even if the questions are popular, are there still holes in what people have already written in previous answers? Do your answers fill in these gaps?
- Are you putting your heart and effort into what you write? Are your answers the best they could be?

If you're doing that - writing, helpful, awesome and worthwhile answers to solve problems and make the Internet a better place - then I don't think I can fault you for anything. Reputation's nice, and yeah, for some people, maybe that's their primary motive for participating on SE. That's okay, I guess, but it's not going to keep you going here. If you're churning out loads of low-quality posts to try to farm rep, it's gonna catch up to you eventually. But if you want to help people, if you write well, if you answer well, if you put in effort, then . . . eh. I'm not sure I really care *what* questions you answer. You're doing some good.

Now, I usually don't answer questions already on the HNQ list for a couple reasons:

- They get lots of answers, so chances are good that someone's already said what I have to say.
- I often don't *like* the sort of questions that get on the list.
- The odds of people reading all the way down to my answer get slim once the question gets more and more answers - see the [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18014/274942).

The third point is actually an interesting one. I've found that once a question is on the HNQ, answering it often yields no more dividends in terms of reputation than answering a normal question soon after it's posted. In other words, even if you do go fishing on the HNQ, you're not going to have much luck unless you get there soon on each question.

Of course, if a question I answer gets on the HNQ list, I'm not going to complain. I just don't seek them out.

On a final note, sometimes my motivations for writing answers here aren't too altruistic (moderating . . . yeah, okay, that comes from altruism alone). Honestly, some of the time I'm here just because I love to write about astronomy and physics. And it turns out, funnily enough, that even though I'm not a great writer, me writing here helps people. Which is awesome. And that drives me to keep doing it, and to do it to help people.

TL;DR: You're volunteering your time here to make the Internet a better place. So long as you're primarily here to do that, it doesn't matter on which questions you do it, in my book.

Comment: Personally, I'd say my motivation for contributing to SE is primarily to help other people, and I don't really care about reputation except insofar as it shows people were helped by my answer.  I guess I was just concerned with the secondary effect of picking up reputation points through an "easy-points" channel, and if that was considered a "fair" way of using the site.

Comment: Actually, yes, I don't answer most of the "hot questions" I read, for the reason you mentioned, that the question already received plenty of good answers.  Sometimes, even if I don't answer, I occasionally insert a helpful comment, possibly to clarify something that was unclear, misleading, or not strictly true in the answer, or something I didn't understand.

Comment: BTW, the only real reason I contribute to questions on the HNQ list is that they catch my eye.  I guess that _is_ the purpose of that list after all!  :-)

Comment: @Gooseberry Heh, yep, it's working just like it's supposed to. Then . . . yeah, I think you're doing what you're doing for all the right reasons. Using the HNQ to reach more people is good thing, really.