# Which answer should I mark as correct - the first comments or the first answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, accepted-answer

After asking [Player disappears when it collides with a tagged object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59184990), one user, in the comments section, asked one question and, with my answer, he asked another question and added a consideration that solved my problem.

I thanked him and told him to create an answer for the question.

Immediately after doing that, [an answer pops-up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59185385/7109869), from another user, that apart from solving the problem, made some considerations on performance (that are helpful but not required to solve my problem).

The user that helped me solve the problem in the comment section then shared [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59185450/7109869).

I ended up marking the answer of the user that helped me solve the problem in the comment section as correct and adding a comment to upvote the other answer as it has an extra considerations related with performance, however, as I am having doubts if my approach was the right one, I decided to share it here to hear your feedback.

Comment: It is your accept vote. You're free to do whatever you like with it. You can even decide to change it after 6 months, or un-accept in 6 years.

Comment: That is a reasonable course of action. Remember that a few days later a truly great answer may come, that's the kind of question (and pair of answers) where there's room for improvement; indeed there's a hint in the comments that you've accepted an answer and so they have finished assisting you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) says:

> Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.

So it's **entirely** up to you.

Stack Exchange is [not about who gives the fastest answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18014/295232), it's a [library of detailed answers to every question about certain topics](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It's fine to accept a later, more complete answer, even though it may have drawn inspiration from previous answers (we have to trust the author here that they didn't *copy* it, they probably know they'd have to [attribute](/help/referencing) it).

If you feel accepting the detailed answer doesn't reward the other (now-accepted) answer enough, consider posting a [bounty](/help/bounty) and award it to the 'simple' answer.