# How to flag the invalid downvoting activity

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should be done to people who downvote strategically?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17538/what-should-be-done-to-people-who-downvote-strategically)
>   [What can I do if I'm the victim of serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting)

Recently for [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699925/iterating-through-a-liststring/) all the answers (correct) were downvoted for no reason, I just marked them flagged for moderator's attention, Is there any other efficient way to take some action on such activity ?

Comment: what you did, was the corrective action Jigar

Comment: @Lucifer: No, it is not.

Comment: but it is a serial downvoting. @TimManishEarth

Comment: @Lucifer No it's not. The down votes where on posts by different persons, that's perfectly valid (and easily reversed by the community). Serial (up/down)voting is when the votes target the same person.

Comment: @Sathya Not exactly, this isn't serial downvoting.

Comment: Possibly related: [If you just witnessed tactical downvoting, is it a reportable offense?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting-is-it-a-reportable-offense) and [What should be done to people who downvote strategically?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17538/what-should-be-done-to-people-who-downvote-strategically)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no reason to flag answers for moderator attention because they've been downvoted.

Downvotes are anonymous and can be cast for any reason a user may choose. Moderators cannot and should not reverse downvotes based on their own opinions. The job of a moderator is not to decide whether an answer is "correct" or not—that's the job of you and everyone else with the reputation to cast votes! Moderators should only be flagged in cases where their intervention is required.

The only situation where downvotes would be reverted is when they are associated with a pattern of abusive behavior, such as in the case of [serially downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) a **particular user**. And in that case, there is an automated script that runs periodically to detect and reverse this type of abuse.

If you come across a post that you don't think deserves to be downvoted, then you should upvote it. Eventually, community consensus will decide the appropriate score for that particular contribution.

Comment: That is true but I believe there should be some control over moderators too, No one should be able to downvote without any reason, and community generally checks the recent questions I believe

Comment: I would say that seeing as all the answers bar one were downvoted (and that essentially all answers are the same), it _is_ suspicious.

Comment: @oded Maybe someone thought the answers weren't very good. At least one of them failed to format his code correctly, although I've already fixed that. Doesn't look terribly suspicious to me; these aren't exactly high-quality answers.

Comment: that could be valid scenario but then here first answerer shouldn't be downvoted I believe

Comment: @Jigar There *is* control over moderators; I have no idea what that has to do with this question. People can downvote for whatever reason they want, and that's completely by design.

Comment: @The Establishment makes sense, Thanks!