# Voting on other's answers to make my answer look better

Tags: discussion, voting

Is it selfish or frowned upon not to upvote another answer (even if its right) so yours will rise to the top faster?

I find myself wanting to un-upvote posts so my answer will do better... But I have been able to push back the evil thus far.

Comment: If you goal is to collect internet points rather than to help people, you may be on the wrong site.

Comment: All I can say is: [**Sportsmanship**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/805/sportsmanship)

Comment: Or if your answer is correct too then you could upvote theirs out of politeness and hope they do the same for you.

Comment: Your answer will do better if it's better. If you want more votes, improve your answer. Other "tricks" are pretty pointless.

Comment: It also costs you reputation points to downvote answers. You probably won't come out ahead.

Comment: See also: [What should be done to people who downvote strategically?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17538)

Comment: Even more, to avoid *temporary* downvotes (retracted later, to hide the trace, or to get the lost reputation back), [in 2009](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting/18046#18046) the following nasty but required limitation was implemented: *"To help deal with the "tactical downvoting" problem, we have radically reduced the window for undoing votes. There is now only the very briefest of windows where you can undo a vote. (edit: this was increased to 5 minutes) After that, the vote is permanently "locked in", until the post is edited."*

Comment: Thanks guys. It's not like I've ever actually done it, I just wanted to ask to make sure there was a consensus

Comment: Totally as an aside, it's sometimes nice to just see how the community works. For any question, [you can use `/posts/xx/timeline`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/190032/timeline) to see on which day votes were cast. Like I feel that [my late answer to some question](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eDjne.png) is better than the first answer. In [the timeline](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Har6D.png) you'll see that often only the accepted, highest voted answer is upvoted. But sometimes both answers, or *only* my answer gets a vote. I don't care about reputation, but I find it amazing how things work.

Comment: Related: [Is the "down-voting most/all answers that aren't yours" pattern considered harmful?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4012) and [The answer to tactical downvoting problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22771)

Comment: In general, go with your intuition. It's usually right about such matters. The voting system is designed to get the best, most useful answers to the top, and the least helpful and/or incorrect answers to the bottom. Using it any other way is sketchy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No-one is telling you how to vote, your votes are your own.

However, if you *do* upvote competing answers, there is a nice shiny silver badge to be earned: [Sportsmanship](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/805/sportsmanship).

> Up voted 100 answers on questions where an answer of yours has a positive score.

Comment: You stole my badge link! *blows whistle* Unsportsmanlike conduct! 50 rep penalty! Automatic badge revocation!

Comment: @animuson: Had you posted your comment as an answer, I could have upvoted it! Here on Meta I haven't gotten that shiny badge yet!

Comment: @animuson: As for the link, I nicked it from the badges page fair and square. :-P

Comment: Ah, the witty banter of programmers. I love this place.

Comment: Why isn't there an `unsportsmanlike` badge: 100 downvotes on questions where you have an answer.

Comment: Because badges are there to promote positive behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

I tend to revisit questions I answered when I notice a new upvote. After I revisit the question, I upvote the other (correct) answers. So (if other users act the same way) upvoting a "competing" answer leads to more upvotes on your answer. Having said that, for me, the gaming factor in Stack Overflow is not to have the highest scoring answer in each question, but to earn the maximum upvotes overall.

Comment: Or the most badges; Sportsmanship badge, here I come! :-p