# Clarifying an answer not a question

Tags: discussion

Can I include my some hints that may others get helped in stack-overflow or there is other stack-exchange website to place the question with solution?

I would like to give users some hints not a question how can I ask question in stack-overflow that I can say this is not a question but answer to help.

Comment: You're saying you just want to post tips? I don't think just "tips" fit [so]'s Q/A system. After all, it *is* a Q/A system. It's made for *questions and answers*.

Comment: You can start by improving the FAQ

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking for.

Comment: Could you tell us what kind of hints you mean?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/

Answer (score 3):

> there is other stack-exchange website to place the question with solution?

**All** Stack Exchange websites *welcome* questions with solutions.  That's why there's the "**Answer your own question**" checkbox at the bottom of the "Ask Question" page.

If you have a solved problem that's a good fit for a SE site (check the FAQ to be sure) and hasn't already been asked, then you should definitely **share your knowledge**.

Just remember that the question and answer both have to meet the same quality standards as any other posts; just because they're provided together doesn't mean that both shouldn't be fine as independent posts.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by ***blahdiblah***, all Stack Exchange websites allow you to answer your own question/s.

In fact, in the [Stackoverflow FAQ's](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) it specifically says that It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

That being said, the community does not always look at it as an honest attempt on the OP's part to genuinely help others (although, that is the point of SE). Unfortunately, nothing can be done about how the community reacts to such situations. I have in the past commented on a question (I tried to hunt that comment down before posting this, but either it is buried in my list of comments, or probably deleted with the question.) that this SO cannot be treated as a blog post. That does contradict the fact that asking and answering your own question is encouraged. However, I said that because the user, in my opinion, was doing this for gaining reputation. His list of questions kinda made me feel that. Some of them were pretty simple questions and mostly duplicates of other questions.

Occasionally, you will also find your own solution and post an answer for it: [Android Facebook Post On Wall Without Dialog Warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9945153/450534)

Sometime, things like this will happen too: [Is it a desirable action to flag self-answers which are obviously rep farming?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119503/196875).

I my opinion, if you are talking about a few questions (that you would like to answer yourself) now and then that really address something that does not have a clear solution, go right ahead. However, if you are looking at posting several such Q&A's, I would be cautious. SO is community driven, regardless of whether they took it in the right spirit or not. You could consider a blog of your own and link to it in your profile. When a relevant question comes up, link to it again with an excerpt of the necessary code.

If your intention is to genuinely help by sharing your knowledge (keeping ***blahdiblah*** suggestions in mind), you could also consider marking your answer as a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/196875). This way, no one can accuse you of any wrong doing whatsoever.

My two cents....