# Separated partial reputation based on questions and on answers

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I've seen a lot of profiles with a much higher reputation than mine, owned by people who never answered a single question.

(Which I think is OK, and fair. After all, they probably are much more useful to the SO community than I am.)

But I really think it would be nice having separated reputations on each profile page, measuring how much of the reputation is made a) by answering questions and b) by asking them.

PS: I'm not asking to change the way the overall reputation is computed.
PPS: This question *should* be a duplicate - I just cannot believe anyone else has thought about that before. But I was not able to find anything.
PPPS: This is my first meta question, so please "be gentle" :P

Comment: -1: I disagree. +1: being gentle. I don't see how such thing will improve the site or what benefit it has. What about reputation from edits? From accepting answers? How will you show this? If you're just curious, it's easy enough to write Data Explorer query that will give you those stats.

Comment: qv [Chart to show reputation points grouped by event type](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152413/chart-to-show-reputation-points-grouped-by-event-type) which is *totally* on my personal todo list...

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: (I wish I could explain that in Portuguese, but I'll try anyway). Let's think about this scenario: if, say, Jon Skeet answers a question, I dare say the first thing most people will think is that that answer is *right*, just by looking at his freaking high score. So what I'm saying is that everyday someone is giving a "ad-hominen +1" to questions and answers, based solely on the author's score. And if we can't avoid that, we could *at least* give users a tool for making that +1, statistically, a little bit closer to the truth.

Comment: So your worry is people who've got all their rep from asking questions answering them @rsenna? It's more complicated than that though... I have over 20k. If I answer a question on C++ it still looks like I have 20k, even though I know barely anything about it at all. So, you'd have to break it down by tag as well...

Comment: So would you place this information next to the question/answer in that case (I'd like to see this information *somewhere* (in the profile) but theres probably not space by the answers)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: I see your point. And I agree it is not enough. I still believe it would be an improvement (and I believe that small improvements have a lot of value).

Comment: @RichardTingle: I think that simply placing that information into the user profile will make *some* difference.

Comment: Then I can completely get behind this; preferably [in chart form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152413/chart-to-show-reputation-points-grouped-by-event-type)

Comment: @RichardTingle Why not both? :) But I agree, If I had to choose, I would pick having a chart too.