# Reverse the effects of the global reputation recalc of March 2010 on previous actions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [New reputation changes. Is applying it retroactively fair?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42885/new-reputation-changes-is-applying-it-retroactively-fair)
>   [Should the weight of question upvotes be reduced?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42769/should-the-weight-of-question-upvotes-be-reduced)

My proposal is to reverse the effects of the recalc on all actions that have occurred before the recalc. My argument for this: Just because something is free doesn't mean that there isn't a contract of sorts in play (not legally binding of course, but still important). If a user does things according to the FAQ and guidelines, they should reap the benefits that come with these actions, such as No `no-follow` in their link, and all other points-required features of the site. To take these all away (or even some of them) from people who have already earned them isn't fair.

To sum it up in 2 words: **Grandfather Rights**

For those who haven't noticed yet, [The global reputation recalc of March 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010)

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42885/new-reputation-changes-is-applying-it-retroactively-fair

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was [discussed on the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/) and we won't be pursuing that for several reasons:

1. It's complicated -- and complicated means hard to explain and understand, which increases the support burden.
2. Leads to discontent as "old" users gained rep using different rules and may enjoy significant advantage.
3. It's more honest and equitable to say we value answers more than questions across the board as a sort of gravitational constant rather than "oh, except for these users during this time period".

That said, there will be some short-term pain with this change, but we believe it will make the entire trilogy Q&A ecosystem healthier for *everyone* in the long run.

Comment: Only #2 is even remotely reasonable. The others fall under the bait and switch category.

Answer (score 0):

> To take these all away (or even some of them) from people who have already earned them isn't fair.

Life isn't fair, and I'd argue it's not fair to give people higher reputation than the reputation algorithm says they've earned.

Comment: When I'm an old lady in a rocking chair with cats on my lap, I'm going to have a saying: "There's no fair this year."

Comment: @Ether Thanks for the value added.

Comment: @cee Life has been pretty fair to me. I make lots of money, have no kids, am happily married to a women who doesn't want kids, go on vacation for 3 months per year to FL and the Bahamas, and snowboard in the winter. Life's fair to winners. Winners always win.

Comment: Until they don't, at which point they're no longer a winner.