# Can't place a bounty on meta questions?

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, meta

I've done quite a bit of searching but don't see anything regarding it.

**I am unable to place a bounty on my own, or anyone else's question here on meta.**

I see the featured tab is still available, with featured (bounty) questions, so it doesn't look like bounty has been turned off here altogether.

Comment: I've looked at questions I've posted with no answers, old questions, questions with different required tags, and lots of other people's questions - no more bounty link.

Comment: I'm seeing the link - how old are the questions? Do you have a bounty on another question already?

Comment: @ChrisF - I have a selection of questions: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2915/pollyanna#questions from which to choose.  Sorting by most recent there are many within the last month or two that have no answers.  I can't see any bounty link on any of them.

Comment: @ChrisF There are only [9](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53245/ "Popular Demand") [featured](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73734/ "Lance Roberts") [questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74979/ "Yi Jiang") [and](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75081/ "Pekka") [none](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74000/ "Mark Trapp") [of](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64275/ "Arjan") [them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74201/ "marcgg") [are](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74983/ "badp") [from](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75130/ "Andrew") Pollyanna

Comment: Here's an example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47667/accept-rate-vs-answers-received - I don't get a bounty link.

Comment: @Grace - Yeah, I'm not currently running any bounties.  Are we only allowed to run one bounty at a time?

Comment: Yes, you're only allowed to run one bounty at a time. I'm able to run bounties here, still. Maybe you're restricted because of the ol' lotteries you used to run. ♪

Comment: For the sake of posterity, post a screenshot of your inability to post bounties.

Comment: **DRAMATIC GASP!**  Don't tell I've been *blacklisted!?!*

Comment: @Grace - I did check myself but when I saw your comment deleted I didn't answer.

Comment: @Grace - I don't want to clutter the op: http://i.imgur.com/zeZpE.png

Comment: Well, that's *very* mysterious. I'm suddenly a lot more confident in my conspiracy theory than any of the more plausible theories.

Comment: Glad that balpha sorted this out - I'll fix the delete code (only usable by mods in this case) to properly remove bounties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue resolved in chat. Relevant bit of the transcript starts around [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/465032#465032); <del>will create a conversation out of it after discussion ends (if I remember).</del> and here's the [full transcript](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/bounty-bug-75866). Unfortunately, it has a lot of side conversation mixed in.

Comment: Would you please sum up the relevant bit? I got lost at bacaon.

Comment: I don't even know anymore. The timeline on that post is... confusing. I think it had something to do with a post being deleted while it still had an open bounty. This was back in the one-bounty-at-a-time days, so the system thought the user had one going, but since the post was deleted he couldn't award it, either. Anyways, it's since been resolved.

Comment: Apparently one may only have one bounty going at a time.

Comment: That was true at the time, but not anymore. See [this bounty update blog post](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/).

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be related to a deleted question with my bounty on it, apparently still active:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45826/test-question-please-avoid-upvoting-will-be-defenestrated-by-april-27th

Comment: I recently had a bounty question from SO moved here, and I have the same issue. The user that received the bounty doesn't have a MSO account.