# Total cap on Question rep

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please charge rep for questions after threshold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/please-charge-rep-for-questions-after-threshold)

I've been thinking about the recalc lately and a few other things I've read in regards to people using this site to do their homework, or write their companies programs for them one problem at a time..etc.   Personally I believe that in time, as the site becomes more and more popular the weighting of question upvotes will need to be modified again.  So before that can happen I'm curious to see what you think of a Total cap on rep received via questions.

Seriously, if you're above 2K rep, still asking questions regularly and not answering any there's an obvious problem.  So what do you think of once X number is reached a user can only receive rep by ANSWERING questions?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/please-charge-rep-for-questions-after-threshold

Comment: @downvoter pretty close, yeah. Just seems more simplistic this way.

Comment: Is it appropriate to consider (at least some) new posts about changes to the current system as non-duplicates of those marked completed?  Even understanding Jeff and many others would be horribly disinterested in revisiting this so soon, I doubt everyone (including me :P) will shut up about it as we watch how the changes take affect in practice.

Comment: @Gnome: I think it's worth entertaining new discussion on old topics *if* they're begun with an awareness of the previous discussions and the changes made as a result. But there's no point in rehashing every old argument for each new user.

Comment: @Shog9: Agreed; it is helpful to refer to the older discussion, but much of it deals with the old system and none can even address ramifications of the new system.  So I'm wondering if we should try to continue along with the old discussion (marking new Qs as duplicates), continue in new Qs (with links referring to the old ones) or how it should work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like giving no reputation for *any* questions after a particular reputation level -- just because a user has high rep doesn't mean he'll never have good questions again. However, I think it's reasonable to explore the idea of giving out no more than X *total* reputation for questions - say somewhere around 1000?

In my case, I've received 44 (net) upvotes on the questions I've asked on SO. Not counting reputation caps, that counts for <strike>440</strike>220 reputation. If I ask another good question, I think I should still be able to get <strike>+10</strike>+5 rep for an upvote. If I turn into a question pump, *then* that reputation gain should fizzle or cease entirely.

One could get even more fancy by using a sliding scale -- no more than 50% of your rep should come from questions for the first 1000 rep, 20% for the next 5000, etc.. but complicating the formula would probably make it less likely to ever get implemented. Let's keep the back end as simple as possible.

Comment: "I think it's reasonable to explore the idea of giving out no more than X total reputation for questions - say somewhere around 1000?"... EXACTLY!

Answer (score 0):

> Seriously, if you're above 2K, still
>   asking questions regularly and not
>   answering any theres an obvious
>   problem.

Wait, what? Can you elaborate on the "problem"? No one is forced to answer and the website is not about trading answers for questions.

If someone asks a lot of questions and doesn't want or is not able to answer any, it's perfectly fine by me. It would be much worse if the user tried to answer without the needed knowledge.

Comment: @Kop Im sorry I guess I wasnt clear..  Im not saying anyone should be forced to answer or even trade answer for question.  People can still ask all the questions they want, they just wont get any additional if they already have more than X rep pts.

Comment: @Qui: but they help the website; maybe those users can reach 2,000 and do their part editing, and can help that way. Reputation is a measure of how much the community trusts you; it has nothing to do with how good a programmer you are.

Comment: @kop I would agree with that... but is there anywhere you would draw the line?

Comment: @Kop: technically *reputation* is a measure of how much the community values your *posts* (via voting).  this is conflated somewhat into a measure of how much a user is valued, which is part of why rep is not the greatest measure of a user's contribution to the community.  i generally agree with your answer tho -- asking questions, even asking *lots* of questions, isn't automatically a bad thing.

Comment: @quack: are you ~quack? After going through all the trouble of getting ~quack back, even deleting your account and losing all your rep, you changed your name again? :D

Comment: @Kop: that was a long time ago, not much rep was lost (and half of that would've been removed in the recent recalc since it was all on my first question :)