# Reputation from questions needs to be changed

Tags: feature-request, reputation

This is, in part, a plea to the the SO team to investigate what change in activity you are seeing from high answer-rep users and see if there is a pattern of the number of answers dropping off over time.  That is, are your most valuable contributors disengaging from SO?  Because I know I am, from the sheer difficulty of finding worthwhile questions to answer.  If I am not alone, that would be a key indicator that the *primary* value providers in your crowd-sourced system are being driven away. I only have a sample size of one.

Stack Overflow has become inundated with trivial questions, and as [this question and its comments and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/please-charge-rep-for-questions-after-threshold) show, those asking questions, even at 5 rep, gain reputation in vast disproportion to their value-contribution *and more importantly* have a good incentive to continue to flood the site with trivial questions.  Look at the referenced users on that question – many are 20K plus now, solely from asking a stream of questions.

How can it be appropriate that someone accumulates over 26K rep from 1800+ questions like:

- [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)
- [Does Python have a string contains substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-method)
- [Convert comma separated string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/convert-javascript-comma-separated-string-into-an-array)

While awarding significant reputation for questions was necessary in the very beginning to garner participation, that time has long passed.  Over time it's become quite obvious that **questions are only valuable if they are answered – it's answers that provide value to Stack Overflow, not questions.** In the end questions by themselves just provide work.

My request is that reputation from questions be altered in some way to remove the incentive to ply the site with thousands of trivial questions, many of which could be answered by RTFM.

Some possibilities:

- Remove question rep.
- Balance rep from question up and down votes to be equal.
- Cap rep from any one question at, say, 100.
- Cap total rep from questions.
- Limit questions to some ratio with answers.
- Limit question rep not to exceed answer rep, which would have the added incentive for some users of providing double rep-gain from answers as their answer rep catches up to their question rep.

Note, I am not suggesting to kill question *voting* which is an important function for sorting good questions from bad, just the reputation from questions.

Comment: The problem is people upvoting crap questions (and answers, but that's another issue), not people getting rep for upvotes on questions.

Comment: No, a big part of the problem is that getting rep for questions strongly incents posting questions.  I continue to argue that needing an answer is strong enough of an incentive to keep the (good) questions arriving.

Comment: Most crap questions are from brand new users that created an account to ask that one question and will never use the account again, and don't give a damn how much rep it gets.  Much of what's left is people who, even if they're using the account, still care way more about getting an answer than about the rep.  There are *lots* of bad questions from real people with real problems.  The flood of crap isn't coming from people trying to rep farm off of questions.  Most of the rep farmers are people *answering* the crap questions.

Comment: **... and existing reputation from questions be removed from all accounts.**  Yeah, that's not going to go over so well.

Comment: So downvotes on questions would also not see you lose reputation? Or will you make asking questions purely a losing game? Both sound very unattractive to me.

Comment: *"Questions are only valuable if they are answered"* - and answers are only useful if there's a problem that they're solving.

Comment: This also lowers the incentive for making a question better through editing. A question with poor spelling, grammar and formatting may still get an answer, but it is less likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @David: Hah! Wish that were so.

Comment: @Bart: Correct, question downvotes would also have no effect on reputation. Essential, getting an answer would be its own reward, and the quality of the question would determine whether you garner answers. And the rep-gaming by asking a multitude of questions, (many or most of which are already asked and answered if you only bother to search SO) would end.

Comment: @animuson: And programmers just doing their job will encounter legitimate questions as a matter of course.  So there's no need to somehow "generate" questions.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey: a) You seriously think question quality would improve if downvotes didn't hurt your reputation? b) Rep-gaming is a much more serious problem for answers than it is for questions.

Comment: @David: Yes, because the once-off multi-account types don't care anyway, but the rep-farmers will utterly loose their incentive to continue to flood the site with pointless trivia.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey But rep farms *don't* flood the site with pointless trivia *questions*, they flood the site with *answers* to the pointless trivia posted by non-rep farmers looking for people to do their work for them.  Very few people really try to get rep from questions; lots of people try to farm rep without really adding value through answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the best alternatives are:

1. Simply make question down-votes carry the same weight as up-votes, such that a net-zero vote equals net-zero reputation.
2. Not allow rep from questions to exceed rep from answers by more that 100 points.

Answer (score 0):

Arguing that answers are more valuable than questions is a one-sided view of the way content is generated in my opinion.

Questions need to have incentive because they are an essential part of the content generating process. There may be some bad questions, but there are also great questions. Moreover, even bad questions can produce very useful answers.

Comment: I've said it before, and I'll say it again, **we don't need *more* content on SO, we need *higher quality* content**.

Comment: Simply put, removing incentive to put effort into questions will not achieve getting higher quality content. The fact is that the exchange desperately needs more content on a daily basis. New talent and content is very important to the sustainability of the stack exchange community. More content and high quality content are most certainly not mutually exclusive.

Comment: The incentive to put effort into questions is already there - *I need an answer*.  Awarding rep for questions simple creates an incentive to ask hundreds of trivial questions and be rewarded for it.  Can't you see that SO is not suffering a problem of getting questions??

Answer (score -1):

> Questions are only valuable if they are answered

Not really. On their own merit, questions can be decent, original, well researched, thought provoking, well laid out with problematic code provided.
As such they deserve to be part of the voting system, to be voted on based on their quality as a question, and the questioner should receive good or bad rep as a result.

It's arguable that questions are only *useful* with an answer, but that's different to *value*.

> Stack Overflow has become inundated with trivial questions

How can you state that and then propose the resolve is to remove the best thing Stack has to get rid of the poor questions?
By allowing rep change from voting on questions, a bad question receives downvotes and that and a loss in rep prompts the questioner to improve it, a good question receives up votes, attracts more people and likely better answers.

I see time and again on terrible questions the questioner asking "why the downvote", so people are concerned about their rep.
Why should answerers in these scenarios receive rep and not questioners who are the people providing the means for those answering?

Votes alone would be *ok* as the question would eventually be pushed off the main pages, but without a loss in rep people would have less incentive to write good questions or improve their bad ones.
Without their rep going down they're more likely to post the same question again to get it on the first page.
What do they lose?

Answers would degrade as people lose interest in the increase of bad questions, the site suffers badly as a result!

> ...have a good incentive to continue to flood the site with poor questions

People gaining rep from asking questions is an incentive to asking good ones, not flood the site with poor ones. If they do that, they get downvoted and rep is lost or not gained.

There will always be poor questions, from lazy people, people without much of a clue to the code they're asking about but ask anyway, etc. It'll always happen. Voting is the best way to control that, and rep increases the likelihood of a question being improved.

If you have a suggestion to control/remove poor questions feel free to propose it, but removing rep from votes is not it.

> it's answers that provide value to Stack Overflow, not questions. Questions only provide work.

If answers are what provide value, and answers need questions in order to exist, questions are therefore a necessity and as one requires the other for a Q&A site to be decent, questions are at least a gateway to providing value from the answer.
Therefore the question has value in its own right as part of the full Q&A package.

Q *and* A!
Without questions this site would be just.. answers? Answers to what? Both are needed and so both add value.

Your point of view leaves me to understand I'll no doubt be receiving an upvote from you for providing value?

Comment: I never said get rid of *voting* on questions, I said don't award *rep* for questions - voting on questions is critical to SO.

Comment: You completely overlook the fact that in real-life programmers *inevitably* have questions as they do their work - no incentive is needed for asking questions, and getting a quality answer should be reward enough.

Comment: I only skimmed your question. Though, my point was largely still valid as I included the result of loss of rep in most of my arguments. I've edited it to reflect more clearly "no rep awarded" only.

Comment: "On their own merit, questions can be decent, original..."  
- Well, simply, no; without an answer a question on SO is useless. They only have value to me, as a programmer, if they have answers. Otherwise all it tells me is that someone had the same problem, and no one on SO who saw the question had the answer; of course it may well be that no one saw the question because of the other several thousand that hit the site at the same time.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey: "No incentive needed for programmers who have questions" - Questioners may well have a question *anyway*, but as you're not taking rep away from answerers and so they gain rep as an incentive to write good answers, surely rep is therefore an incentive for questioners to write good questions? Besides, why shouldn't questioners be included in the rep and gain privilege? Questioners should receive rep & privileges for asking good questions, or their progress towards privileges hindered from loss in rep for bad questions.. as much as answerers do for answering.

Comment: No, getting an answer is perfectly sufficient incentive to write good questions and to make edits as suggest.

Comment: "without an answer a question on SO is useless" - You missed the point. You're talking about questions being "useless" without answers, but only by the fact a question with no answer is no good to anyone who requires the answer. Fine. However, that doesn't mean the question cannot *also* be evaluated as *good* or *bad* in many ways - ie *value*. Therefore votes and rep awarded accordingly. Your argument can be completely reversed, in that *without questions, answers couldn't exist*. Both are necessary, and neither one can exist in a meaningful manner without the other on a Q&A site.

Comment: James: But my point is that questions already "exist"; programmers doing their job have them as a matter of course.  And questions can and should be voted on; the change needed is to remove or vastly reduce the reputation gained from questions since questions *in and of themselves* provide no value.  If you were to take away SO today, gone, poof, no more, programmers would still have legitimate questions; hence, with SO providing quality answers there is no incentive needed to ask questions here.

Comment: "getting an answer is perfectly sufficient incentive to write good questions and to make edits as suggest" - There are plenty of professional answerers who likely don't care about their rep. In fact, I see many comments which were a great "answer" to the question. They could have easily gained a few rep points putting it in an answer if they cared about rep. People who don't care about rep can ignore it & they lose nothing by gaining it. People who like gaining rep, badges, privileges etc would lose that if taken away. So your way upsets some people, as it is everyone is happy.

Comment: "with SO providing quality answers there is no incentive needed to ask questions here" While there is no incentive to actually ask a question, the rep is incentive to ask a *good* question. Without it, question quality would deteriorate with the loss in incentive and so would the answers, as people don't want to answer bad questions.

Comment: That's pure speculation. I argue that the quality would be vastly improved because (a) the junk questions would diminish and (b) I want an answer, and writing a good question is the best and fastest way to get that.

Comment: What's speculation?

Comment: "Without it, question quality would deteriorate" is pure speculation.

Comment: It is speculation, but my conclusions are derived from experience, common sense, and being open minded to see what is happening now with rep on questions and deduce what is a likely outcome from removing it. It's also speculation to state there will be no detrimental affect from removing rep on questions. It's also far too general to state all questioners don't want or like their rep, privileges and badges. *Many* do want these things and have just as much right to them as answerers. Both are critical to the existence of each other.

Comment: Not meaning to be snarky or condescending, but I suppose I *could* counter with the fact that my experience, actively involved with SO for over 5 years from the very beginning, outweighs your 2 months or so by a long margin.

Comment: You could try, but it would be meaningless. Stack is not the only thing that exists in the world, so experience here is not the only thing one can go by. I've worked on customer service & support systems, been in technical management, programming, on many a forum, etc. Also, it doesn't take many brain cells to work out how effective rep on questions is. For people who don't care it makes no difference with or without rep. Many people do care, & so having the rep entices them to write better questions & improve on them. Basically, it's either *lose*, or *win & lose*. Which is better?

Answer (score -2):

A viable alternative might be to charge a certain amount to ask questions after some initial free limit.  This is what the question linked in the OP asks for and which I add here to suggest that it's time to revisit that request.

Perhaps after 10 freebie questions, it might cost 10 rep to ask a question, after 100 it might cost 100. That will be no problem to those actively participating in the site by answering as well as asking, but it will sure as heck temper the serial (vampire) askers.  this might even be only when questions exceeds answers.

For my part, I'd have no problem paying out some of my reputation earned from answers to ask questions here on SO (being a little over 1/2 way to 100 questions).

Comment: This would just encourage people to make new accounts to ask questions.  That doesn't help anyone.