# How to tell new users with 0% accept rate to improve it?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, accept-rate, new-users

I have seen many new users post many questions and they get answers for it... They often forget to mark the correct answers.... 
How to tell new users with 0% accept rate to improve it?

Comment: With a blunt object?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34922/why-are-consistent-0-accept-rate-users-not-punished

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23321/is-it-appropriate-to-comment-on-peoples-accept-rate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If at all, **politely** would be my keyword. Snarky comments about accept rates will often be removed. Personally I see this more as one of those "discovery" things (a bit like the badges) - so it'll happen automatically in many cases.

Until then, upvotes from other users go a long way to acknowledgement of a good answer.

Comment: +1.  On this occasion, I apologize for the tons of my rant and BS about accept rate, which Marc had to remove.  Being polite works a lot better.

Comment: @Pavel - did I? I honestly didn't notice.

Comment: -1, good answer, but doesn't include instructions, which are (unfortunately) necessary for many new users

Answer (score 3):

I think it should depend on what acceptance rate they have.  If a user has 0%, it's likely that they just don't know how SO works and didn't realize they have to accept an answer for previous question.  In that case I usually post something like this:

> @user: please revisit your previously asked questions and accept some answers.  You can do this by clicking the check/tick mark to the left of the answer just below the votes.  Other users are more likely to answer a question if they see a high acceptance rate.

If the accept rate is above 0% but below a certain amount, I usually write something like:

> @user: please revisit your previously asked questions and accept some answers.  You have currently marked x questions as answered out of a possible y.

I think it's best to stay polite, but sometimes you can't help yourself when a user has accepted 2 out of a possible 37 questions :-)

Answer (score 0):

Mostly people leave comment suggesting to accept answers for other questions. I have seen it work in a few cases.

Other than that, if there is no compelling reason to accept answers, nothing will persuade them to do so.

Comment: Right.  It's surprising how often the new user couldn't figure out how to accept an answer.