# Alert users with low accept rate before they ask a question

Tags: feature-request, notifications, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should users be discouraged from asking new questions until they've accepted a certain % or deleted old unaccepted questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28827/should-users-be-discouraged-from-asking-new-questions-until-theyve-accepted-a-c)

Recently more users with low/no accept rate are asking questions, I think displaying a simple message to the users telling them they should accept answers to their existing questions and outline the benefits:

- Other users are more likely to answer your questions, and faster
- You will get extra reputation
- It's like saying thank you to the person who gave you the answer
- You'll help other people who come across your question, by showing them the best answer
- It only takes a couple of seconds

Also on this alert page (similar to if you click ask a question when your logged out) it should show a list of answers that user has not accepted an answer on.

Maybe it would be an idea to increase the reputation earned for users with low/or only no accept rate when the accept an answer, to say 5.

Stats:

- 76% of questions that have at least 1 answer have an accepted answer.
- 63% of all questions have an accepted answer
- 254,000 questions (out of questions with at least 1 answer) don't have an accepted answer.
- 494,000 questions (out of all questions) don't have an accepted answer
- **Basically over a third of questions don't have an accepted answer**

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20722/what-is-with-people-not-marking-their-questions-as-answered,http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45508/how-to-tell-new-users-with-0-accept-rate-to-improve-it, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23321/is-it-appropriate-to-comment-on-peoples-accept-rate,

Comment: Getting more reputation probably don't matter to them : what they want are answers. What about restraining them from making more active question if they don't have at least x% accept rate ?