# Getting new users to accept answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer

The concept of getting users to accept answers to questions has been asked before, I know.  The questions usually focus on punishing users in some way, prohibiting them from asking if their acceptance rate drops below a certain threshold, a wall of shame for low-accepting users (!!), etc.

Has anyone considered something much more simple?  Would it make sense at all to put one of those yellow strips across the top of a users screen if they have asked > 8 questions, and have an acceptance rate of less than, say, 30%?  Except of course without the button to dismiss it.  Just something stating that they have a low acceptance rate, with a link explaining what that means.

The only time I've ever seen users with acceptance rates that low was when they were new users, had upwards of 8 questions, and zero accepts.

Comment: There are plenty of reminders already. The problem is that users don't pay any attention to them. There's no good reason to assume they'd pay attention to a yellow bar at the top of the screen, either. I'm also skeptical of your claim that the only time you've ever seen users with low acceptance rates is when they were new users with zero accepts. That's not necessarily been my experience.

Comment: This also [sure gets asked a lot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80079/alert-users-with-low-accept-rate-before-they-ask-a-question). **Why are you people so worried about other users' accept rates?**

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80079/ In my question here, I said just displaying a message before they ask a new question. (similar to the message you get if you're logged out and you try to ask a question, but much shorter and to the point).

Comment: I didn't know there were a lot of reminders, I've always accepted answers :)  And I'm not *worried* about it (why is the assumption that people asking this are *worried* about it, or that it's a "big deal"?), I just thought it was a decent idea to make SO a little better, but I see it's already being done more or less.  "Nothing new under the sun"

Comment: Maybe the real question is how do we get people to search for duplicates before posting questions. ;-)

Comment: Indeed.  I should have done a better search beforehand.