# how to get the right answers marked as accepted

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've been reading trough a bunch of answers where somwhere in the coment, the owner of the answer sayd: "Thanks, this is the right answer" but they didnt click on the Accepted button.

So my question here is, should I comment on it and say "nicely done! dont forget to accept it so it is good and closed" Like my problem is I dont wanna play the cop or cleaner, but some people really forget to accept the right answer, or are there "other" guys looking at all the questions and answers and tell them to accept it?

A while ago here was a discussion going on about when to accept an answer automatically so it gets closed. I liked the point where somebody say: "NO, then we loose the kind of human saying it is the right answer". Which is a good point, but maybe an answer after 10upvotes could or should get marked as the right answer, I don't think 10 users give an upvote if the answer is wrong and then we have the human saying "it is the right answer..".

Comment: could you please comment, why you are downvoting, it is just a question

Comment: Hi caramba, never mind the downvoting - see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences. This suggestion has been made before, though, and rejected.

Comment: Welcome to Meta Stack Overflow! See the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: See also: the *entire* Related sidebar, which this question is likely to be a dupe against.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's possibly because a) it's not a very well written question (many misspelled words, poor capitalization and punctuation, and needless phrases like "Like my problem is" and "I liked the point where....Which is a good point", for example), and b) there are dozens of links about the same subject at the top of the `Related` list -->, including [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80084/172661) which seems very similar in content.

Comment: You already saw the discussions here on Meta. Why you think your suggestion is different or special then? Did you miss the fact that ALL discussions requesting to auto accept answers are heavily downvoted?

Comment: @ken thanks for your coment, english isn't my native language

Comment: @Sha yes I missed that fact, I thought it's different because it is not auto accept

Comment: The checked answer should be the one that helped the OP most. You'll come across many questions where the accepted answer has less votes than the highest voted answer. So there's no rough-and-ready rule which answer could be selected automatically. And this is good as it is. Sometimes even no answer fits perfectly but they may still receive upvotes.

Comment: `maybe an answer after 10upvotes could or should get marked as the right answer`, if that were the case, than the checkmark would tell the viewer nothing. The viewer can already see that the answer has ten upvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that reminding the OP to mark an answer is as far as we should go.

If they don't at least you have the answer's score to let users know that the community likes that answer, and even the verbal acknowledgement of the OP is visible to people googling similar questions.

One of the things I absolutely hated about the MSDM help forums is that the Moderators would routinely mark answers on your question as correct, and they would often do it in error.  I don't want to see that come to SO.