# Clarification in FAQ regarding downvotes and max number of votes per day

Tags: feature-request, faq-update-request

FAQ [What is reputation?](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) section should be clarified (mentioned in bold below) relying on section [Vote down questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down):

- Regarding downvotes on questions:

> question is voted down -2 **(0 to voter) [Why?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)**

- Regarding number of votes that could be cast per user per day:

> to reach the maximum you must vote on at least 10 questions. **([Why?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/))**

Comment: These questions are answered here on Meta (see [How does "Reputation" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237) and [Are there any voting limits?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5212)

Comment: That is not a question, that is a proposition for update into FAQ section

Comment: I know, but one of Meta's purposes is to provide more detailed FAQs than the (deliberately concise) site FAQ page.

Comment: Ok. I just mentioned it because, they are present on another SO section [Vote down questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) and I have found such answers just there.

Comment: This is not a question, it is a series of questions, some with answers within the question, I also don't see a proposal

Answer (score 1):

> FAQ What is reputation? section should be clarified (mentioned in bold
>   below) relying on section Vote down questions and answers:

Reputation is easily found in the Help section:
https://stackoverflow.com/help
As it the connection to votes:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

> Regarding downvotes on questions:
>
> question is voted down -2 (0 to voter) Why?

This answer addresses the reasoning behind penalties for downvoting answers, and not questions.  As does the link you have provided.
[Should downvotes on questions attract a larger penalty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83262/should-downvotes-on-questions-attract-a-larger-penalty)

> Regarding number of votes that could be cast per user per day:
>
> to reach the maximum you must vote on at least 10 questions. (Why?)

The link you have provided this also answers your own question.

If you want to understand the psychology of why people vote in certain patterns, I suggest you google some psychology papers.

Comment: That section [What is reputation?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) is not the same as it was 1 year ago

Comment: I know, but it still address the question/suggestion.. no point reflecting on it as it was then

Comment: So, please, flag to remove that question, or remove your answer and then I can remove the question without moderation

Comment: @cubanacan Why?? It can stay here, I answered the question. Whether it is a good or bad answer, is up to the community to decide. Why are you so interested in dismantling this particular post? I flagged your comment as not constructive, this is such a strange encounter