# Is it all about acceptance rate and reputation points?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

Twice i've been told of SO at my low acceptance rate .. and that people will not answer my questions with low acceptance rate

The point i want to ask is, is SO all about reputation points .. or just a good discussion ?

Can you please create a 'hide all matrices view' on SO .. and see if people like that more ?

Comment: I'm seeing excellent answers to this question.  Why won't you accept one?

Comment: @Hans .. well said (-:

Comment: Excellent question!.. In my case, I'm not a sophisticated developer. I've been stuck in a time capsule for 20 years and trying to get up to speed. So I ask many more questions than answer others questions because I just don't know how to answer most of them. Does this make me an outcast in SO?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a courtesy to the people who do help you to reward them as you can - and around StackOverflow, the recognized reward mechanism is up-voting and accepting answers.  You can upvote any answers that help you solve your problem; you give the 'Accept' to the answer that was the most help.  That lets the people who volunteered to help you solve your problem know that you appreciate their assistance.  If you don't show that appreciation, people will show their reluctance to assist by pointing out that you have not accepted many answers, etc.

No - it is not all about acceptance rate and reputation points.  However, they are a big influence on the site.

It's give and take.  You get to give thanks (as is common courtesy) and you get to take the answers.  If you do not like this, I suggest you find an alternative forum to obtain answers to your pressing questions.

Comment: I do upvote what i find good .. i also downvote what i find incorrect .. but the point is these are just feedbacks ... why turn reputation system into the appraisal system of the corporate world !!

Comment: @Vardhan: Accepting answers has other benefits as well. It closes that question as resolved, meaning it will not get bounced periodically by [Community](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community). Also, other users that find the question will see the accepted answer first, saving them some time.

Answer (score 7):

Yup, users really do skip questions of users with low accept rates.  Your last 3 questions have a low number of views, you must have noticed.  And no, I'm pretty sure that everybody likes being able to judge the odds that their effort is going to be productive.  If you don't accept answers often then you'd better ask really interesting questions to draw the views.  It's possible and actually appreciated, just not as easy as clicking a button.

Comment: however one shouldn't accept an answer just to increase the accept rate, after all that means "this answer really helped _me_ the most" and other users might later rely on that judgement

Answer (score 4):

Your accept rate on SO is currently 50%. I've just read [your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/414441/vardhan-varma) which are left unanswered / unaccepted. To me, they are fair enough. However, you should really consider to edit and improve those questions so that you might get better answers, or to post the final answer yourself, for the case you already solved it and no one of the answers has helped in some way to achieve the solution.

Answer (score 2):

One of the benefits of upvoting and accepting answers is that others who happen to have the same problem as you in the future and stumble upon your question can have some guidance as to what helped you the most. Sometimes people will write very detailed and impressive looking answers that don't actually address what your problem was, while other may be able to address your problem in a single line of code or two. The voting mechanism provides insight into the utility of each answer for future reference.

Not to mention that whole be kind and thankful thing... :)

Answer (score 2):

Reputation drives the site's economy. Moderation is mostly handled by the community. As such, a good flow of reputation is necessary. If no one upvoted, the site would eventually suffer from lack of moderation as too few would have the privileges to get the job done.

Additionally, upvoting and accepting answers both indicate the quality of an answer: if it was upvoted, it's a good answer; if it was accepted, it's even better. Remember, Stack Overflow is not just a Q&A site; [it's also a knowledge base](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/). People who don't upvote or don't accept questions are not helping the system run like it should. They don't help identifying the best answers.

Answer (score 2):

> Is SO all about reputation points .. or just a good discussion ?

Stack Overflow is a place to get good, fast answers to questions.

In order to optimize for that, the reputation system and accept rate were developed.

The reputation system provides users with an incentive to answer questions.

The accept rate helps answerers figure out whether the person asking the question is actually going to follow through or not.

In other words, the accept rate is intended to help the question askers - that's you - hold up your end of the deal.

If you aren't sure how to increase your accept rate, considering reviewing this question: [Is a 51% acceptance rate too low?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34919/is-a-51-acceptance-rate-too-low)

Removing the reputation, accept rate, and other site metrics for everyone will reduce the incentive people have to answer questions, and you won't get answers as quickly, or as good, as you are getting now.  However, if *you* don't want to see the numbers and metrics, there are user scripts that can remove them if you use a supported browser.  They will still be there for other users, and you may still get complaints of a low accept rate, but you won't be seeing other people's reputation and accept rate.