# Allow low-rep users to post more than one internal link

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, spam-detection, internal-links

As a new user on all three sites in the trilogy I am trying to write good questions but find one feature frustrating.

I was in a situation where I was posting [a question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/122926/how-do-i-get-excel-to-close-completely-after-creating-a-macro-in-a-personal-workb) and wanted to link to several other questions on superuser to say, "Answers to these questions are not what I am looking for." But the spam filter blocked me and I was only able to link to one question because my reputation is low. (It would be nice if it had let me know that I could only include one link as soon as I tried to add the second rather than waiting until I hit post--but this is a minor quibble.)

My feature request is to allow more than one link in a question no matter the asker's reputation so long as the links are to other questions on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User (or meta).

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33184/dont-limit-the-number-of-internal-links-new-users-can-include-in-questions-at

Comment: "As a new user on all three sites in the trilogy" Actually, you mean all *four* sites of the trilogy :)