# Let me post as many links as long as they are overflow flavored

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Allow low-rep users to post more than one internal link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43608/allow-low-rep-users-to-post-more-than-one-internal-link)
>   [Don’t limit the number of *internal* links new users can include in questions (at least on meta)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33184/dont-limit-the-number-of-internal-links-new-users-can-include-in-questions-at)

I just registered on meta today and was trying to post some links to stackoverflow pages I had questions about, but couldn't post more than 1 link.

**Shouldn't the limit for links be ignored as long as the domain you're linking is stackoverflow, superuser, or severfault?**

I'm not sure how someone is suppose to spam by linking internally to one of these sites... I'd only really be worried about external links.

Thanks

Comment: +1 for very nice title but this is most definitely a duplicate.

Comment: I can't vote to close, but: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33184/dont-limit-the-number-of-internal-links-new-users-can-include-in-questions-at

Comment: My bad, the dupe I flagged for is newer than the one @Farseeker identified. Probably better to close with that one.

Comment: mmm, overflow flavored...