# Earning Reputation for Poor Questions

Tags: feature-request, reputation

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Should the weight of downvotes be increased?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased)
>   [Should we reduce rep bonus for upvotes on posts with a negative score?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/should-we-reduce-rep-bonus-for-upvotes-on-posts-with-a-negative-score)

OK, this may sound like a big change but this is something that I believe could have good impact on the quality of the users questions and answers and would result in reputation being more fair.

**The problem:**

Currently if a question/answer gets up-voted to poster earns rep of 10 points, when it gets down-voted 2 points are being deducted. That scenario works pretty well for answers but unfortunately when it comes to questions there is some areas where I think it fails. For example: poor questions, controversial questions and average questions

**Here is the scenario:**

Someone asks very poor question,

- it gets down-voted: say it gets 3
  down-votes
- some nice and patient so user comes
  along and edits that question to
  improve it
- other so users see
  question with 3 downvotes and say: "hey it does not deserve to have minus vote, lets
  upvote"
- the question ends up with the rep 0, but the OP of that poor question ends up with the reputation of: +24!

They are some users that frequently ask rather poor quality questions, and end up with a pretty high reputation

similarly average question:
 - a question that is being initially down-voted and up-voted only because other users think that it did not deserve to have -1 rep. The OP ends with higher reputation

controversial question:
 - a question that attract many up-votes and down-votes earns the user many rep points

controversial answer:
 - same as controversial question

Basically it seems that this type reputation system in some scenarios rewards people for the behaviour that should not really be encouraged.

**I think there is a simple solution to that:**

Instead of earning reputation for each up-vote and down-vote recorded it could be earned based on the overall **vote balance** for the question or answer.

Currently if a question gets 3 downvotes and 2 upvotes the question shows "vote balance" -1 but the OP earns +14 points on reputation (-6 for 3 downvotes, +20 for 2 upvotes). In proposed solution he would have got -2 points as question shows "vote balance" -1

> For example
>
> user1 - someone asking
>   rather poor questions,has 3 questions
>   and 1 answer
>
> ```
>     Vote Balance   up-votes    down-votes   reputation earned
> Q1:      -1             2            3               +14 (+20 -6)
> Q2:      -1             0            1                -2
> Q3:       0             3            3               +24 (+30 -6)
> A1:      -1             0            1                -2
> --------------------------------------------------------------
>                                    Total Reputation: +34
> ```
>
> user2 - a new user, asking ok
>   questions, but ones that do not bring
>   that much attention
>
> ```
>     Vote Balance   up-votes    down-votes   reputation earned
> Q1:       0             0            0                 0
> Q2:       0             0            0                 0
> Q3:       0             0            0                 0 
> A1:       1             1            0               +10
> --------------------------------------------------------------
>                                    Total Reputation: +10
> ```
>
> user3 - providing controversial answers
>
> ```
>     Vote Balance   up-votes    down-votes   reputation earned
> A1:       1             11          10               +90 (+110 -20)
> A2:      -1             4            5               +30 (+40 - 10)  
> --------------------------------------------------------------
>                                    Total Reputation: +120
> ```

If we applied the logic on awarding the reputation based on each question overall performance then it would be as below

> user1 - someone asking
>   rather poor questions,has 3 questions
>   and 1 answer
>
> ```
>     Vote Balance   up-votes    down-votes   reputation earned
> Q1:      -1             2            3                -2
> Q2:      -1             0            1                -2
> Q3:       0             3            3                 0
> A1:      -1             0            1                -2
> --------------------------------------------------------------
>                                    Total Reputation:  -6 (perhaps rep less then +1 could be allowed)
> ```
>
> user2 - a new user, asking ok
>   questions, but ones that do not bring
>   that much attention
>
> ```
>     Vote Balance   up-votes    down-votes   reputation earned
> Q1:       0             0            0                 0
> Q2:       0             0            0                 0
> Q3:       0             0            0                 0 
> A1:       1             1            0               +10
> --------------------------------------------------------------
>                                    Total Reputation: +10
> ```
>
> user3 - providing controversial answers
>
> ```
>     Vote Balance   up-votes    down-votes   reputation earned
> A1:       1             11          10               +10
> A2:      -1             4            5                -2
> --------------------------------------------------------------
>                                    Total Reputation:  +8
> ```

It think that it would better represent the user's contribution.

Also it could be a part of the solution for [Handling “Problematic” Stack Overflow participants](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20696/handling-problematic-stack-overflow-participants/20729#20729) as the users that continuously ask poor question would end up with reputation less then 0 (if allowed)

I have added this solution as an answer to [Should the weight of downvotes be increased?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased/39054#39054)

Comment: Are you talking about questions (original version) or answers (current version)?

Comment: I am sorry,  I made a mistake in edit, I should have been Questions

Comment: I lost you at "simple solution". Rephrase or be prepared to be downvoted to hell. No, that's not a threat, that's Meta.

Comment: This question is actually a good illustration of the problem, currently at -1: 2 dowwnvotes, 1 upvote and still earned me +6 reputation ;)

Comment: @John, my apology - I have edited the the question a bit, hopefully it will be easier to follow now.

Comment: @kristof, for now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42769/should-the-weight-of-question-upvotes-be-reduced/42781#42781

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to be addressed sometime soon I believe:

[Should the weight of downvotes be increased?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I am not a frequent visitor on meta and did not see it before asking the question

Comment: @kristof: 1. don't apologize, but you will learn the *Meta way* soon enough. 2. this is one of the top 5 `feature-requests` asked on this site. At least it's `status-planned` :)

Comment: Nope, apparently that's not going to be addressed soon. (it's `status-declined`)

Answer (score 0):

I think the weight of votes in general on questions should be modified, maybe even to a semi-log scale where one-or-two votes don't mean much as the question is reasonable, but if it goes stellar then you get good rep.