# Why were 9 of my questions deleted? and -100 for each of them?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions, penalty

Why were 9 of my questions deleted? (Stack Overflow) and -100 for each of them?

I do not know why I lost 100 points for each (I don't see it in [this faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean/5222#5222)). If you look at [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34537/acidzombie24) you'll see I ask a lot of questions and generally know how to ask questions. Typically I delete my own, I only remember one instance ATM when I did not delete my own (I posted, went to bed. Heard my question was tagged wrong, migrated to another site and delete due to confusion all before morning came). If you look at [my rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34537?tab=reputationhistory#sort-top) you can see a lot of posts were deleted and I went down 900 points. Why? And why the reputation penalty?

I also feel some are valid, like why I shouldn't [use exes to output my HTML on webpages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441635) and [Why does C++ not have some functions that are standard in nearly all other libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479152).

Comment: So far the two answers below say it may have been a group attack. It wouldnt be the first time i was criticizes or attacked by a group but i am curious if any of them would tell me why if it was indeed a group attack. (My email always has been public and email is pretty anonymous)

Comment: I doubt that people who would league into a "flag offensive" campaign are the kind who just express their disagreement with words.

Comment: *If you look at my profile you'll see i ask a lot of questions and generally know how to ask questions.* Sure you do. 580 and climbing...

Comment: @circular reference, what is your point? That we need more answers, not questions? Or that he's doing going work?

Answer (score 19):

I checked, and these are all valid offensive votes, on questions that were already heavily downvoted.

You might consider whether some of your questions are really appropriate for Stack Overflow if that many community members find them offensive.

Bear in mind that repeatedly asking many low quality questions is [grounds for timed suspension](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20696/handling-problematic-stack-overflow-participants) as well.

While I don't think this *necessarily* holds true in your case (although since you have asked 600+ questions, there are bound to be some outliers), it's something to consider. On your user page, you have three full "pages" of questions with a score of -1 or lower, all the way down to -7. (Note that most of these have been deleted by mods, so they won't be visible unless you are a moderator.)

Comment: I did notice many were low ranking but were they really 'offensive'

Comment: @acid: I don't know about anyone else, but I found the two you linked to be factually iffy, brusquely opinionated, and in the case of the c++ one verging on insulting (it carries an implication of "How come you guys are so stupid?"). Still, I'd have stuck with a down vote.

Comment: **600** questions. Dude.

Answer (score 6):

From your profile:

> Stop asking me to 'accept' more
>   answers.

I guess this has annoyed someone to the point of organizing an attack against you.

Comment: If this is the reason, the users who did it are in the wrong, not acidzombie24.

Comment: Indeed. I didn't mean that it was acidzombie's fault, I just pointed out the possible fact.

Comment: People stopped doing that as often. I'll take that out. When the accept feature came out i had 34% and people kept bothering me about it.

Answer (score 4):

Losing 100 points and having the question deleted, happens most likely only when you were [flagged as offensive by 6 people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work-in-stackoverflow).

I doubt all of your questions were offensive, so it looks rather like you were a victim of a group attack. Refer to this to team@stackoverflow.com (unless they check directly from here).

Comment: Considering that it needs 5 or 6 flags in total to be flagged, I would agree that it is potentially a team effort.