# Why was this question marked as duplicate?

Tags: support, closed-questions, close-reasons

I posted this question:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92786/questions-about-bounties

It was hastily "closed as exact duplicate". However, when I looked at the article that it references, neither of my questions were referenced.

What kind of mechanisms are in place to "politely disagree". If someone looks at the subject without understanding what's being asked, what recourse do people have?

In my humble opinion, the fastest way to get people to stop posting on StackOverflow is to instantly close a question. If someone takes the time to write out a question, it's a contribution of content to the community. Give other members the opportunity to read it, understand it and answer it. What mechanisms are in place to prevent hasty closing of questions?

Comment: Before you jump to conclusions about whether you're question has been done wrong, make sure you **fully read the duplicate** - in this case, specifically **"What is automatic awarding?"**

Comment: I'm not jumping to conclusions. I'm voicing my disapproval of hasty closing of questions. It encourages people to not contribute content to stackoverflow. I read that part. Why is only half rewarded?

Comment: @Homer6: So, you didn't read the part where it specifically answers that question?  Where it says "At the end of the bounty period, if the bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, eligible answers can be automatically awarded half the bounty amount." and then goes into the algorithm?  That part?

Comment: The link that Brandon provided below has an accepted answer that contains the following quote: "people can and should appeal their posts being closed if they don't feel that it was done correctly". Flaming about me voicing my disapproval only encourages people further to not post. Why would I take the time to write out logical concerns when I'm going to get jumped on?

Comment: Or is what you're actually asking in that question for a change as to how the automatic bounty system functions?  Because it looks like you're just asking what happened.

Comment: @Won't - which algorithm are you referring to? I only see *how* it selects to automatically award points. I don't see *why* the reward is only half.

Comment: @Homer6: I posted it above in my comment-- "**At the end** of the bounty period, **if the bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty**, *eligible answers can be automatically awarded half the bounty amount.*"  So, if you don't select the winnar by the end of the bounty, it will be awarded by the system.  The (rough) algorithm is listed below.

Comment: @Won't: These are details on *how* it's awarded. There is no mention of *why* it's only half of the value of the bounty. This seems like something that requires explaination.

Comment: @Homer6: *That* is a very valid question and worthy of a [discussion] or [feature-request].  I also wouldn't think it would be a dupe, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You are talking about two different *whys* - "why what happened, happened" and "why it was designed that way".  Go ahead and ask the second question, but to everyone here you've given a strong impression that you are asking the first question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question is answered in the FAQ.

You may have set a 500 reputation bounty, but you let it expire rather than award the bounty yourself. So Community awarded only half the bounty automatically.

> At the end of the bounty period, if
>   the bounty starter has not manually
>   awarded the bounty, eligible answers
>   can be automatically awarded half the
>   bounty amount.

As for multiple bounties, the user was not able to divide up the bounty, instead they offered multiple bounties (one at a time) and awarded them to different users.

As for recourse on a question you believe was incorrectly closed, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6211/reopen-question-incorrectly-closed-as-duplicate).

Comment: You're right, the first answer is in the FAQ. However, the second one isn't. Thanks for the link, it was useful. Any comments on hastiness of closing and how it can discourage questions?

Comment: @Homer6, I'm sure there have been several discussions about closing questions, first two I can find are http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26014/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69618/. The general consensus is that given the sheer amount of questions SO receives, it's worth discouraging a few posters rather than lowering the quality and increasing the signal to noise ratio.

Comment: @Homer6, I think that the closing (as duplicate) in the case of your first question was actually meant to be helpful, as in "All of your problems can be solved here".

Answer (score 1):

I think that your question is fully  addressed by the duplicate question linked.

(Bounty is awarded by 1/2 if the time expired, and you have to manually grant it to give the full bounty. No mention of divided bounties. These are questions with multiple bounties)

If you want to disagree, you can do it here as you've just done.
BTW if the question has been closed, it's usually the fact of the community flagging it multiple times, or a moderator. 
They usually know what they are doing.

Comment: "No mention of divided bounties. These are questions with multiple bounties". This confirms that this was a unique question.

Comment: Well you can also go [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users) if you want. I will edit the CW to reflect this part as well.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, there are two recourses open to you if you believe your question was closed incorrectly as a duplicate.

First, the community can vote to reopen.  Usually what happens is that you would make your plea in the comments of the question, and if you win over enough people, they can vote to reopen.

Second, is to flag for moderator attention.  Succinctly describe why you believe it is not a dupe.  If your argument is marginally persuasive, you will probably succeed.  Note, it is a bit different here on Meta.  Dupe closures are much less likely to be reversed, imo.

Comment: Duplicate closures here have been reversed plenty of times. It's not really any less or more strict than it is on the main sites.

Comment: Thanks. This is useful information. Any idea on how to flag for moderator attention? Also, any comments of the hastiness of closing questions and its relationship to discouraging community involvement?

Comment: @GraceNote: I've gotten that impression over time.  It might be that there are so many closed-as-dupes here.

Comment: @Homer6: Search for the word "flag" on this page and you will probably figure that part out.  As for discouraging involvement... eh.  There seems to be plenty of it going on.  And there has been for a few years.  So I don't think its having much an effect.

Comment: Well, it certainly supports that perspective when a not-insignificant portion of all incoming posts tend to get replicated at least 3 times (like the recent issue with code blocks), and how all our old stuff still gets re-asked every now and then. We do get an inordinate number of duplicates here.